# How to get partial results from Subsets[]?

Tags: combinatorics

Oftentimes I am searching for the first item in a sequence that satisfies some property. For example, consider *the subsets of prime numbers whose total is prime*. To start generate them, we could naively try `Subsets[Range[100]]`, which fails (as it should) yielding the message:

```
Subsets::toomany: The number of subsets (1267650600228229401496703205376) is too 
large; it must be a machine integer. >>
```

But is it too much to ask for a list of the first 500 subsets (by any canonical ordering), or perhaps just the *n*th subset?

Ok, so I found the following in the details section, which gives (if possible) the *s*th subset:

> **Subsets**[*list, nspec, {s}*]

But sadly, this is not at all what I need - according to the docs:

> **Subsets**[*list, nspec, spec*] gives the same result as
>   **Take**[**Subsets**[*list, nspec*], *spec*], provided that the elements specified
>   by *spec* are present.

So Mathematica performs the *entire computation* and only when finished (and it won't finish) does it perform a `Take` at the end. I would appreciate some guidance as to the preferred tactics when dealing with this problem of , i.e. "how to tell Mathematica *start processing the intermediate results on the fly*" (like you can with `AsynchronousTaskObject` and friends).

Comment: See [(9554)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9554/lazy-lists-of-tuples-and-subsets)

Comment: What are you talking about? The docs make it clear: it gets the same *results*, *NOT* that it does the same *thing* (do the work, then select). Try eg `Subsets[Range@1000, All, {1*^100, 1*^100 + 10}]`, works fine.

Comment: The 1st item in a list of all subsets of the prime numbers in canonical order for which the elements total to a prime is the set {2}. I make this comment to suggest you might want to place constraints of the size of the subsets.

Comment: Also related: [(75431)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75431/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Whoa - is that a bug in SE? I marked the question for close based on "...easily found in the documentaton...", not as *duplicate* (though I'd agree). Or did I mark it as the latter, and need to cut back on the opium consumption?

Comment: @ciao You did *not* mark as a duplicate.  Unfortunately the banner incorrectly asserts that all close votes are for the same reason.  I know this has come up on Meta Stack Exchange if you care to search for it.  It seems to be "intended behavior" even if it is false. :-/

Comment: @ciao Here are some links for you: [(926)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/926/), [(2519)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2519/), [(54917)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/).  Of note, in some cases the votes *are* differentiated: [(188688)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188688/)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Cheers, will check them out...