# how to remove Null's from output?

Tags: list-manipulation, output, procedural-programming

I'm a math enthusiast and I'm looking for examples of rare divisibilities,
let's look at the following one:

```
Table[If[Mod[n!, n^(2 n)] == 0, Print[n]], {n, 1, 1000}]
```

Here n=1 is the only result and I have 999 Null's.

What should I do to avoid getting large output, where thousands of results are Null's?
I mean I would like Mathematica producing a result if occurs, else completely nothing. In the example above, I would like to get "1" only, without the rest of output, where are 999 Null's.

I tried this:

```
Table[If[Mod[n!, n^(2 n)] == 0, Print[n],{}], {n, 1, 1000}]
```

But it only replaces Null by {}.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: `Divisible[n!, n^(2n)]` might be a little more explicit than `Mod` in this case.  Also, this will never be true for integers greater than `1`: `n!` is less than `n^(2n)`, and no number can be divisible by a greater number!

Comment: duplicate Q/A: [How to avoid returning a Null if there is no “else” condition in an If contruct](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3700/125) with several answers including one by  @Mr.Wizard featuring the _vanishing function_ `##&[]` as the third argument of `If`: `Table[If[Mod[n!, n^(2 n)] == 0, n, ## &[]], {n, 1, 1000}]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Table[If[Mod[n!, n^(2 n)] == 0, n], {n, 1, 1000}] /. Null -> Sequence[]
```

> {1}

```
Cases[Table[If[Mod[n!, n^(2 n)] == 0, n], {n, 1, 1000}], _?NumericQ]
```

> {1}

```
Select[Table[If[Mod[n!, n^(2 n)] == 0, n], {n, 1, 1000}], 
 NumericQ[#] &]
```

> {1}

```
DeleteCases[Table[If[Mod[n!, n^(2 n)] == 0, n], {n, 1, 1000}], Null]
```

> {1}

Comment: thanks very much for so vast and quick answer

Answer (score 2):

Without comment on whether this is the best solution for your paticular problem, this can be achieved by the following pattern:

```
Table[
    If[condition, value, Unevaluated@Sequence[]],
    ...
]
```

`Null`s will stay, `Sequence[]`s will disappear.

For large problems this may be better:

```
Reap@Do[
    If[condition, Sow[value]],
    ...
]
```

Check `Sow`/`Reap` in the documentation.

Comment: thank you, I haven't seen Sow / Reap commends before.  and I didn't expect a vast reply few minutes after asking question :)