# Sequence evaluation in an If statement

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation, hold, sequence

```
In[1] := {a, b, Sequence @@ {}, c}
Out[1] := {a, b, c}

In[2] := {a, b, Sequence[], c}
Out[2] := {a, b, c}

In[3] := {a, b, If[1 == 0, x, Sequence @@ {}], c}
Out[3] := {a, b, c}

In[4] := {a, b, If[1 == 0, x, Sequence[]], c} 
Out[4] := {a, b, Null, c}
```

How do you explain this peculiar sequence of commands? In the last example, my guess is that the sequence is evaluated on the if statement itself, shrinking it to `If[1 == 0, x]` so that the false evaluation gives `Null` instead. Doesn't `If` have a HoldForm or something on the arguments to ensure that this doesn't happen? And why does example 3 work in that case? My application is a long list of the form `{a,b,x,c}` or `{a,b,c}` and I want to make the `x` appear in the list under a condition, without writing `a,b,c` twice (it would be equivalent to `If[cond,{a,b,x,c},{a,b,c}]`).

Comment: `{a, b, If[1 == 0, x, Evaluate[Sequence @@ {}]], c}` returns `{a, b, Null, c}`. I think it is caused by the order of evaluation.

Comment: I propose closing this as a duplicate of [(3700)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3700/121).  In my answer there I refer to `SequenceHold` as the explanation for "shrinking" to `If[1 == 0, x]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree, although the answers here and there both add helpful information on this phenomenon, so linking them is probably sufficient. I didn't know the stuff about `Unevaluated[]` and `##&[]` that you mention in the other answer either.

Comment: Okay, I shall close.  I don't know if it's the same on [Math.SE] but here duplicates are rarely deleted, so yes, this post and its answers will remain linked from 3700.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Sequence` is treated a bit specially.  It does not get "evaluated to a result", but instead as the documentation explains:

> Sequence objects will automatically be flattened out in all functions except those with attribute SequenceHold or HoldAllComplete.

This means that even though `If` has attribute `HoldRest`, the expression `If[1 == 0, x, Sequence[]]` will be changed to `If[1==0, x]` *before* the `If` itself gets evaluated.  The result of `If[1==0, x]` is `Null`, so that's where the `Null` comes from.

The alternative `If[1 == 0, x, Sequence @@ {}]` does not contain `Sequence[]`, only `Sequence`.  The `If` gets evaluated *first*, resulting in `Sequence @@ {}`, which is evaluated to `Sequence[]` and finally flattened out.

---

This is a typical problem with using `Sequence[]` and `If` together and the simple solution is

```
If[1 == 0, x, Unevaluated@Sequence[]]
```

Answer (score 3):

`Sequence` has non-standard evaluation rules. You can work around them like so.

```
seq := Sequence

{a, b, If[False, x, seq[]], c}
```

> ```
> {a, b, c}
> ```

```
{a, b, If[True, x, seq[]], c}
```

> ```
> {a, b, x, c}
> ```

Updated to conform with the observation made by Szabolcs in his comment below.

Comment: The `SequenceHold` attribute needs to be assigned to the head that contains the `Sequence[]`.  Here `SetAttributes[seq, SequenceHold];` is not needed.  Your example will work the same without it, `seq = Sequence` is sufficient.  The evaluator will only flatten out a literal `Sequence[]` in `If` before evaluating the `If`.  `seq[]` is not `Sequence[]` so it won't be flattened out before `If` is evaluated.  Once `If` is evaluated, it yields `seq[]`, which then is evaluated to `Sequence[]` which is then flattened out inside the `{...}`.

Comment: @Szabolcs. +1. I have corrected my answer accordingly.