# I want to construct a function than the output is "Sequence"

Tags: functions

For example if the input is x and x<10 the output is Sequence[x,0],if x>10 the output is Sequence[0,x]
but obviously

```
Which[#<10,Sequence[#,0],#>10,Sequence[0,#]]&
```

does not work.
How to solve this problem? Thank you!

---

but I find

```
Piecewise[{{Sequence[#, 0], # < 10}, {Sequence[0, #], # > 10}}] &
```

is worked minutes age why?. I feel very confused.

Comment: `Sequence @@ Which[# < 10, {#, 0}, # > 10, {0, #}] &`?

Comment: `Which[# < 10, Unevaluated@Sequence[#, 0], # > 10, 
  Unevaluated@Sequence[0, #]] &` I will leave it as a comment, I'm not good at explaining evaluation.

Comment: Sequence takes a list, so your function is fine if you do `Sequence[{#,0}]...`

Comment: @N.J.Evans and it will *subsequently* return a list. In other words, `{a, Sequence[{b,c}], d}` evaluates to `{a,{b,c},d}`, not `{a,b,c,d}`

Comment: Oops, you're right. I was focused on the fact that the original version returned an error and didn't even pay attention to that. @kguler and Kuba got it though.

Comment: Closely related: [(3700)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3700/121) -- my answer there explains the situation in some detail, though each method will need minor adaptation.

Comment: `Sequence` is not a function to use lightly, particularly as the head of a result. Is there some compelling case for using it here in preference to, say, `List`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f1 = Which[# < 10, ## &[#, 0], # > 10, ## &[0, #]] &;
f2 = ## & @@ Which[# < 10, {#, 0}, # > 10, {0, #}] &;
f3 = ## & @@ {Append, Prepend}[[1 + Boole[# > 10]]][{#}, 0] &;
f4 = ## & @@ {Identity, Reverse}[[1 + Boole[# > 10]]][{#, 0}] &;
f5 = Which[# < 10, {#, 0}, # > 10, {0, #}] /. List -> Sequence &;

f1 @ 1
```

> Sequence[1, 0]

```
f1 @ 11
```

> Sequence[0,11]

```
f2 @ 1
```

> Sequence[1, 0]

```
f2 @ 11
```

> Sequence[0,11]

```
f3 @ 1
```

> Sequence[1, 0]

```
f3 @ 11
```

> Sequence[0,11]

Comment: Just what I would have written myself.  (Well `f1` and `f2` at least.)