# Matching Symbol or Subscript, but not Symbol arguments of Subscript

Tags: pattern-matching

I'm trying to get a list of all the variables in a symbolic expression.  Some are named with `Symbol`s, some are named with `Subscript`-ed symbols.

I can get a list of the `Subscript`-ed symbols with:

```
DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr, Subscript[_Symbol, _Symbol], Infinity]
```

I can get a list of `Symbols` with:

```
DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr, _Symbol, Infinity]
```

The problem with that second `Cases` statement is that it returns subscripted symbols in two parts-- the "base" and the "subscript".  That is, `Subscript[a,b]` will return two symbols: `{a,b}`.

How do I construct a pattern such that I get back a list of all the symbolic variables of an expression, whether or not they're represented as subscripted?  For example:

```
DeleteDuplicates@Cases[a+Subscript[b,c]*Subscript[d,e]^f,pattern,Infinity]
```

returns `{a,Subscript[b,c],Subscript[d,e],f}`?

Comment: What should it return on (for example)  `Subscript[f[t + t1], e + k]`?

Comment: @belisarius, I'm not so concerned with forms like that as I don't expect them in the input.  The only place I have `Subscript` heads is when it's a subscripted variable such as `Subscript[r,bat]` where `r` and `bat` are unassigned symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the very definition of a kluged-together solution (although I like the idea of replacement rules with side-effects), and it's not well-tested, but here's something that works for your example.

```
expr = a + Subscript[b, c]*Subscript[d, e]^f;

DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Reap@Cases[
  expr /. Subscript[a_Symbol, b_Symbol] :> (Sow[Subscript[a, b]]; temp[])
  , _Symbol
  , Infinity
 ]
(* {a, f, Subscript[b, c], Subscript[d, e]} *)
```

The first replacement replaces the subscripts with the `temp[]` (which will not match a `Symbol`) while `Sow`ing the `Subscript`ed symbol. It then runs `Cases` to find the symbols, `Reap`s to get the `Subscript`s, `Flatten`s so that all the symbols are together in one list, and finally runs `DeleteDuplicates` (`Union` works as well as used by `belisarius`).

Just as `belisarius` said about his answer, this is probably not the best solution, but matching a `Symbol` while *not* matching the `Symbol` when it has a particular `Head` is something I don't know how to do easily.

#### Update

We could also use the mysterious [`vanishing function`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3705/29734):

```
DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Reap@Cases[
  expr /. Subscript[a_Symbol, b_Symbol] :> (Sow[Subscript[a, b]]; ##&[])
  , _Symbol
  , Infinity
 ]
(* {a, f, Subscript[b, c], Subscript[d, e]} *)
```

The interesting bit here is

```
expr /. Subscript[a_Symbol, b_Symbol] :> (Sow[Subscript[a, b]]; ##&[])
(* a + f *)
```

The mysterious `##&[]` removes all mention of the `Subscript`s, and `f` takes the place of that entire term.

Comment: I like this best as it appears to only make one pass through the expression-- I don't know if that's actually more efficient, but it feels it would be.  I borrowed from @belisarius to replace your use of `temp[]` with `Unique[][]` because it feels less likely to step on a common function name.  The vanishing function gives me something to study up on...

Comment: @Omegaman. That's why I like the vanishing function idea, as instead of replacing with some arbitrary expression, it removes the symbols completely (and actually it's not all that mysterious). I also have a standard `Protect`ed head `temporaryPlaceHolder` that I use for things like this so as to avoid clashing with already-defined names. Thanks for the accept!

Comment: …and in the latest version, the "vanishing function" is now called `Nothing`.

Comment: Both solutions may lead to incorrect answers depending on the value of `expr`. For example, the one that uses `temp[]` will fail for `expr = (Subscript[a, c] - Subscript[b, c])*f` while the one that uses the vanishing function will fail for `expr = (1 - Subscript[b, c])*f`. Using Omegaman's comment and replacing `temp[]` by `Unique[][]` succeeds in both cases by preventing `(Subscript[a, c] - Subscript[b, c])` from being replaced by zero and `-Subscript[b, c]` from being replaced by `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Surely not the best way:

```
expr = a+Subscript[b,c]*Subscript[d,e]^f
pat = Subscript[_Symbol, _Symbol];
Union @@ {Cases[expr, pat, Infinity], 
          Cases[expr /. pat :> #, Except[#, _Symbol], Infinity] &@Unique[]}

(* {a, f, Subscript[b, c], Subscript[d, e]} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the complexity of the actual expression, this very simple solution may work better than `Cases`:

```
expr = a + Subscript[b, c]*Subscript[d, e]^f;

Variables[expr /. x : Except[_Plus | _Times | _Subscript] :> Times @@ x]

(* ==> {a, f, Subscript[b, c], Subscript[d, e]} *)
```

It uses the built-in function [`Variables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html) which is designed to identify variables in polynomials. It can identify subscripted variables, too (as a side effect of it's ability to return anything that isn't simple enough to be decomposed as part of the variable list). To apply it here, all you have to do is convert the expression such that it contains only addition and multiplication operations (in addition to the atomic and subscripted parts). This is what the replacement rule does. It turns anything more complicated into `Times`, which in this case allows the exponent in `Power` to be counted as a variable, too. Then the variables are identified correctly.

Comment: +1 for a practical solution that works on my example expression, but the actual expressions I'm processing are not polynomial and seem to choke Variables.