# PlotMarkers in GeoListPlot do not work

Tags: geographics

I try to use `GeoListPlot` to draw some points on a map. According to the manual, `PlotMarkers -> {Automatic,s}` should plot the points using the default point markers at size s, but this does not work. Also setting `PlotMarkers -> None` and `Joined -> True` still does show the default point markers on the line connecting the points - e.g.

```
GeoListPlot[GeoPosition /@ Table[{i, i}, {i, 20, 30}], 
 PlotMarkers -> None, Joined -> True]
```

Do I make here a syntax error or is this a bug?

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the PlotMarkers from your image?

Comment: Use an empty string: `GeoListPlot[GeoPosition /@ Table[{i, i}, {i, 20, 30}], 
 PlotMarkers -> "", Joined -> True]`

Answer (score 7):

This should illustrate how different settings for `PlotMarkers` are interpreted by `GeoListPlot`:

```
GeoListPlot[{{Entity[
      "AdministrativeDivision", {"Maine", "UnitedStates"}], 
     Entity["Mountain", "MountRushmore"]}, {Entity["Country", 
      "Mexico"], 
     Entity["City", {"Seattle", "Washington", "UnitedStates"}]}}, 
   Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> #] & /@ {Automatic, None, {} &, ""}
```

[image]

In the last two examples, I'm using the excellent suggestions by Bob Hanlon and Mr. Wizard for turning off the markers altogether.  You can see how they both interact with the legend.

When you use `PlotMarkers -> None` you are doing two things: turning off any polygon shading for the given geographic entity, and opting not to use a different shape marker for each list.

The setting `PlotMarkers -> {g,s}` where `g` is a graphic and `s` is a size, is listed in the documentation for [`PlotMarkers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html), not for [`GeoListPLot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoListPLot.html).  You can test it to see that it does work for `ListPlot` and `ListLinePlot`.

If you wish to use a custom plot marker, then you can do something like this, but notice that it breaks the legend,

```
GeoListPlot[{{Entity[
    "AdministrativeDivision", {"Maine", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Entity["Mountain", "MountRushmore"]}, {Entity["Country", "Mexico"],
    Entity["City", {"Seattle", "Washington", "UnitedStates"}]}}, 
 Joined -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.02]]}], 
   Graphics[{Green, Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.08]]}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Did you intend to write *see below that PlotMarkers -> None has no effect* or are you alluding to a different problem?

Comment: I did intend it - the example shows that `PlotMarkers -> None` is the same as `PlotMarkers -> Automatic`

Answer (score 4):

A bit of experimentation shows that the value of `PlotMarkers` may also be a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html):

```
GeoListPlot[
 GeoPosition /@ Table[{i, i}, {i, 20, 30}]
 , PlotMarkers -> (Print[#] &)
 , Joined -> True
]
```

> ```
> GeoPosition[{20,20}]  
> GeoPosition[{20,20}]  
> GeoPosition[{21,21}]  
> GeoPosition[{21,21}]  
> GeoPosition[{22,22}]
> ```
>
> ...

Therefore a solution that actually eliminates the markers rather than making them transparent or small is to use `PlotMarkers -> ({} &)` or even `PlotMarkers -> (##&[] &)`(see [How to avoid returning a Null if there is no "else" condition in an If contruct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/how-to-avoid-returning-a-null-if-there-is-no-else-condition-in-an-if-contruct/3705#3705)):

```
GeoListPlot[
 GeoPosition /@ Table[{i, i}, {i, 20, 30}]
 , PlotMarkers -> ({} &)
 , Joined -> True
]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 - It would be interesting to use those function slots to allow custom graphics objects as the plot markers.

Answer (score 3):

I think its a bug.
I personally would use JasonB's solution.

But here is some other stuff.
You could modify your Table to only two points

```
GeoListPlot[GeoPosition /@ Table[{i, i}, {i, 20, 30, 10}], 
Joined -> True]
```

or you could use `PlotStyle` to increase the thickness of your line to cover the markers.

```
GeoListPlot[GeoPosition /@ Table[{i, i}, {i, 20, 30}], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.04]], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 - I am just boggled that they include an example in the documentation that doesn't do anything.