# How to generate a table with i != j?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to generate a table with two indices (say, i and j) such that elements with i = j are omitted. How to achieve it ? Following is a simple example of what I want to do.

```
A = Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}];
```

But I do not want the elements like

> {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3} etc

in the table.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Playing with `Nothing`:

1) In-process:

```
Table[If[i == j, Nothing, {i, j}], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]
```

2) Post-process:

```
Replace[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}], {i_, i_} -> Nothing, {2}]
```

Comment: Came here to post this but with `Sequence[]` instead. Thanks for `Nothing`! :)

Answer (score 13):

[`Delete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Delete.html):

```
a = Array[List, {4, 4}];

Delete[a, Array[{#, #} &, 4]]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}},
>  {{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}},
>  {{3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}},
>  {{4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}}}
> ```

Or, inspired by kglr's answer, with [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) and [`IdentityMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IdentityMatrix.html):

```
Pick[a, IdentityMatrix[4], 0]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}},
>  {{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}},
>  {{3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}},
>  {{4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}}}
> ```

---

## Benchmark

With many methods provided I think it is time for a benchmark.  I do not have `Nothing` in version 10.1 so I shall use my old standby "vanishing function" from [How to avoid returning a Null if there is no "else" condition in an If contruct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/how-to-avoid-returning-a-null-if-there-is-no-else-condition-in-an-if-contruct/3705#3705) in its place.

```
n = 1000;

(* for post processing methods this timing must be included in the total *)
a = Array[List, {n, n}]; // RepeatedTiming // First

DeleteCases[a, {a_, a_}, 2] // RepeatedTiming // First

Table[If[i == j, ## &[], {i, j}], {i, n}, {j, n}] // RepeatedTiming // First

Partition[#, n - 1] &@Permutations[Range@n, {2}] // RepeatedTiming // First

Select[#, DuplicateFreeQ] & /@ Outer[List, Range@n, Range@n] // 
  RepeatedTiming // First

Delete[a, Array[{#, #} &, n]] // RepeatedTiming // First

Partition[SparseArray[ConstantArray[1, {#, #}] - IdentityMatrix[#]][
      "NonzeroPositions"], # - 1] &[n] // RepeatedTiming // First

Array[List, {n, n}, {1, 1}, DeleteCases[{##}, {a_, a_}, {2}] &] // 
  RepeatedTiming // First

Pick[a, IdentityMatrix[n], 0] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.00833
>
> 0.419
>
> 0.560
>
> 0.2670
>
> 0.491
>
> 0.00460
>
> 0.0351
>
> 0.412
>
> 0.0274

So even including the time to build `a` my `Delete` approach is considerably faster than any other method yet proposed.  Second fastest is kglr's `SparseArray`, or `Pick` inspired by it.

Answer (score 7):

```
Partition[#, 3]&@Permutations[Range@4, {2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Or

```
Select[DuplicateFreeQ] /@ Outer[List, Range@4, Range@4]
```

Comment: If the ranges of the two iterators are the same I think this is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I like yours too :)

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** Two variations on `Array` (from Mr.Wizard's answer), one using the fourth argument to delete unwanted cases, and the second using a function in the first argument that deletes unwanted cases. Both can handle non-square arrays easily.

```
ClearAll[pF2, pF3]
pF2 = Array[List, {##}, {1, 1}, DeleteCases[{##}, {a_, a_}, {2}] &] &;
pF3 = Module[{dif}, dif[a_, a_] := ## &[]; dif[a__] := {a}; Array[dif, {##}]] &;
```

Examples:

```
And @@ (pF2@## == pF3@## & @@@ {{2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {4,  4}, {4, 3}})
```

> True

```
pF2[2, 2]
```

> {{{1, 2}}, {{2, 1}}}

```
pF2[2, 3]
```

> {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 3}}}

```
pF2[3, 4]
```

> {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{3, 1}, {3,  2}, {3, 4}}}

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[pF1]
pF1 = Partition[SparseArray[1 - IdentityMatrix[#]]["NonzeroPositions"], # - 1] &;
```

Examples:

```
Grid[Prepend[{#, pF1 @ #} & /@ Range[2, 5], {HoldForm@n, 
   HoldForm@ pF[n]}], Dividers -> All, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice idea to use `IdentityMatrix`; I added a variation, with credit of course, to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Yet another way:

```
a = Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}];
Pick[a, IdentityMatrix[Length[a]], 0]
```

Comment: Beat you to it, but +1 nevertheless. :^)

Answer (score 5):

```
A = DeleteCases[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}], {a_, a_}, 2]
```

\begin{array}{ccc}
 \{1,2\} & \{1,3\} & \{1,4\} \\
 \{2,1\} & \{2,3\} & \{2,4\} \\
 \{3,1\} & \{3,2\} & \{3,4\} \\
 \{4,1\} & \{4,2\} & \{4,3\} \\
\end{array}

Comment: Thanks, it is working fine with independent i & j, but not with functions involving  i & j, for eample A = DeleteCases[Table[PE[j] - PE[i], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}], {a_, a_},  2] is giving four elements, not two {{0, -PE[1] + PE[2]}, {PE[1] - PE[2], 0}} AM I doing something wrong here ??

Comment: @user49535, it gives `{{0, -PE[1] + PE[2]}, {PE[1] - PE[2], 0}}` when I run that command string in my computer. May be it will change if you have defined PE-function? Because it is work good if PE is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

Another suggestion is to use [**KroneckerDelta**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerDelta.html) and a [**DeleteCases**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) likeso:

```
DeleteCases[
  Table[{i, j} (1 - KroneckerDelta[i, j]), {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}], {0, 
   0}, Infinity] // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 3):

```
MapIndexed[Drop] @ A


Column @ %
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use `Delete` and `Diagonal`:

```
A = Array[List, {4, 4}];

Delete[A, Diagonal[A]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 4 ;
ArrayReshape[Last[Reap[Do[If[i != j, Sow[{i, j}]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]]], {n, n - 1, 2}] 
(* {{{1,2},{1,3},{1,4}},{{2,1},{2,3},{2,4}},{{3,1},{3,2},{3,4}},{{4,1},{4,2},{4,3}}} *)
```