# In a given unsorted list, find the maximal ascending sublists of at least two contiguous elements

Tags: list-manipulation

In a given unsorted list, find the maximal (strictly) ascending sublists of at least two contiguous elements.

```
input={1, -1, 2, 3, 4, 0, -2, 5, 0}
```

and

```
output={{-1,2,3,4},{-2,5}}
```

Comment: Strictly ascending or just nondescending?

Comment: For reference this is also a Wolfram Challenge question "Ascending Sublists".

Answer (score 5):

```
SequenceCases[input, {a_, b__} /; Less[a, b]]
```

> {{-1, 2, 3, 4}, {-2, 5}}

And, to shed two keystrokes from @1066's answer:

```
Split[input,Less]/.{_}:>(##&[])
```

> {{-1, 2, 3, 4}, {-2, 5}}

Comment: Could you explain `{_}:>(##&[])`?  I think that we are replacing singletons `{_}` with nothing, but don't understand how `:>{##&[])` is accomplishing that...

Comment: @Jonah, please see  [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3705/125) and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8877880) .

Answer (score 4):

```
Cases[Split[input, #2 > #1 &], {_, __}]
```

> {{-1, 2, 3, 4}, {-2, 5}}

Answer (score 4):

Here is a variation of @Henrik's answer that uses [`TakeList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeList):

```
ascending[list_]:=Module[{len = Range @ Length @ list},
    x = Append[0] @ UnitStep[Differences[list] - 1];
    d = Differences[Prepend[0] @ x];
    b = Pick[len, Clip[d, {0, 1}], 1];
    e = Clip[d, {0, 0}, {1, 0}];
    spec = Pick[len, e, 1] + 1 - b;
    TakeList[Pick[list, x+e, 1], spec]
]
```

And, a variation of @user1066's answer that is a bit faster:

```
split2[list_] := DeleteCases[Split[list, Less], {_}]
```

According to my tests, `ascending` is the fastest:

```
a = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, 10^6];

r1 = f[a]; //RepeatedTiming (* Henrik 1 *)
r2 = f2[a]; //RepeatedTiming (* Henrik 2 *)
r3 = ascending[a]; //RepeatedTiming
r4 = Cases[Split[a, #2>#1&], {_, __}]; //RepeatedTiming (* user 1066 *)
r5 = Split[a,Less]/.{_}:>(##&[]); //RepeatedTiming (* kglr 2 *)
r6 = split2[a]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2 === r3 === r4 === r5 === r6
```

> {1.1, Null}
>
> {0.24, Null}
>
> {0.17, Null}
>
> {0.641, Null}
>
> {0.67, Null}
>
> {0.39, Null}
>
> True

*(I didn't include @kglr's first answer or @swish's answer because they are orders of magnitude slower)*

Answer (score 2):

```
f[a_] := Module[{b, startpos, endpos},
 
 b = Differences[Subtract[1 , UnitStep[-Differences[a]]]];
 (* for "nondescending" use this instead:*)
 (* b = Differences[UnitStep[Differences[a]]];*)
 startpos = Flatten[Position[b, 1]] + 1;
 endpos = Flatten[Position[b, -1]] + 1;
 If[startpos[[-1]] > endpos[[-1]], endpos = Join[endpos, {Length[a]}]];
 If[startpos[[1]] > endpos[[1]], startpos = Join[{1}, startpos]];
 Take[a, #] & /@ Transpose[{startpos, endpos}]
 ]
```

Now,

```
f[{1, -1, 2, 3, 4, 0, -2, 5, 0}]
```

> {{-1, 2, 3, 4}, {-2, 5}}

## Edit

Here is the same function accelerated by `Nearest` (instead of `Position`) and a compiled routine to produce the sublists (instead of `Take`):

```
f2[a_] := Module[{b, startpos, endpos},
  b = Differences[Subtract[1, UnitStep[-Differences[a]]]];
  (*b=Differences[UnitStep[Differences[a]]];*)
  {startpos, endpos} = Nearest[b -> Automatic, {1, -1}] + 1;
  If[startpos[[-1]] > endpos[[-1]], endpos = Join[endpos, {Length[a]}]];
  If[startpos[[1]] > endpos[[1]], startpos = Join[{1}, startpos]];
  Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {startpos, _Integer}, {endpos, _Integer}},
    a[[startpos ;; endpos]],
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True
    ][a, startpos, endpos]
  ]
```

Test:

```
a = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, {1000000}];
r1 = f[a]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r2 = f2[a]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r1 == r2
```

> 1.0
>
> 0.23
>
> True

Answer (score 2):

```
Map[Take[a, #] &, 
    SequencePosition[
        ListConvolve[{1, -1}, a, 1], {x_, y__} /; AllTrue[{y}, Positive], 
        Overlaps -> False
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, -1, 2, 3, 4, 0, -2, 5, 0};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3}

```
Cases[{_, __}] @ SequenceSplit[list, a : {b_, c__} /; b < c :> a]
```

{{-1, 2, 3, 4}, {-2, 5}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, -1, 2, 3, 4, 0, -2, 5, 0};
```

Grabbing the @eldo's pattern and using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[Split[list, Less], {___, a : {b_, c__} /; b < c, ___} :> a]
```

> {{-1, 2, 3, 4}, {-2, 5}}

Or using `Pick`:

```
AscendingSequenceQ[l_] := AllTrue[Differences[l], # > 0 && Length[#] == 1 &]

Pick[#, Not@*AscendingSequenceQ /@ #] &@Split[list, Less]
```

> {{-1, 2, 3, 4}, {-2, 5}}