# Vanishing function and Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, conditional, hold, return-value

Within `Manipulate`, I want to vanish certain controls if other controls satisfy a specific condition. The simplest case is to consider two checkboxes, `x` and `y`, where `y` vanishes if `x` is selected.

I have heard of the vanishing function `## &[]` or `Unevaluated[Sequence[]]` (from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/how-to-avoid-returning-a-null-if-there-is-no-else-condition-in-an-if-construct)), but it doesn't seem to do what I want. Consider the following code

```
Manipulate[x,
 Control[{{x, 0}, {1, 0}}],
 Dynamic@If[x == 0, Control[{{y, 0}, {1, 0}}], ## &[]]]
```

which yields

[image]

What I want is

[image]

but I'm getting

[image]

Surprisingly enough, using `Grid` in the following manner solves my problem

```
Manipulate[x, Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"", Control[{{x, 0}, {1, 0}}]},
    If[x == 0, {"", Control[{{y, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, ## &[]]}]]
```

Any idea why? How do I fix my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version will not produce any extra vertical space

```
Manipulate[x,
  {{x, 0}, None},
  Dynamic @ Column[If[x == 1, c1, c2]],
  Initialization :> (
    c1 = {Control[{{x, 1}, {1, 0}}]};
    c2 := {Control[{{x, 0}, {1, 0}}], Control[{{y, 0}, {1, 0}}]})]
```

Its two states look like

[image: x0]

and

[image: x1]

#### Update

Although the above solution using `Manipulate` to do everything works well enough, I think it better to localize the variables with `DynamicModule`. Like so:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0, c1, c2},
  Manipulate[x,
    Dynamic @ Column[If[x == 1, c1, c2]]],
  Initialization :> (
    c1 = {Control[{{x, 1}, {1, 0}}]};
    c2 = {Control[{{x, 0}, {1, 0}}], Control[{{y, 0}, {1, 0}}]})]
```

Comment: This look good, but I would prefer to keep the `If` in the code, making it slightly shorter.

Comment: @samwolfe. That would be nice, but I don't see any way to do that and not have additional vertical space.

Comment: I think when using `## &[]` within the `Grid` you don't get the spacing. I wonder what's happening internally in Mathematica.

Comment: @samwolfe. When I evaluate your `Manipulate`  expression using `Grid`, I get exactly the same result as your first example without `Grid`.

Comment: @samwolfe. I made a small change in the code so it now behaves exactly as you show in your post.

Comment: I realised I was missing something. I changed the code of the `Manipulate` with `Grid`. Please check it now.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Manipulate[x, Control[{{x, 0}, {1, 0}}], 
 Dynamic@If[x == 0, Control[{{y, 0}, {1, 0}}], Invisible[# &]]]
```

or

```
Manipulate[x, Control[{{x, 0}, {1, 0}}], 
 Dynamic@If[x == 0, Control[{{y, 0}, {1, 0}}], ""]]
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it seems I get an extra spacing which I would like to avoid. To see what I mean, comment `, 
 Dynamic@If[x == 0, Control[{{y, 0}, {1, 0}}], Invisible[# &]]` and compare it.