# If-statement does not evaluate if condition is true

Tags: list-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid returning a Null if there is no “else” condition in an If contruct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/how-to-avoid-returning-a-null-if-there-is-no-else-condition-in-an-if-contruct)

I know there are other ways to solve this problem. Just because I'm curious I tried:

```
Map[If[# == 1, , #] &, {2, 1, 3, 1, 4}]
```

This should return a list without the value 1, because when the statement is true it should do nothing. The solution should be:

```
{2,3,4}
```

and not

```
{2,Null,3,Null,4}
```

Why is it not working as I expect?

Comment: [`DeleteCases[{2, 1, 3, 1, 4},1]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeleteCases.html)

Comment: thank you ssch. I know that this works. Just wanted to know if there is a possibility to get the solution out of the if directly.

Comment: `Map[If[# == 1, Unevaluated[Sequence[]], #] &, {2, 1, 3, 1, 4}]` in that case :)

Comment: Frink, please try to make an effort to find existing questions which address your problem before asking a new one.  In this case a search for "If Null" would have brought up the proper question as the first result.

Comment: Another duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3447/5

Comment: @rm-rf Indeed. Should we close one of these (3447/3700) as well?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think so. I did vote to close 3700 as a dupe of 3447 when it was asked (as did rcollyer), but it expired. Perhaps we should close 3447 -> 3700 (even though the former is older) because 3700 has a better title and more views (probably because it is easier to search for)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `If` statement is actually

```
If[# == 1, Null, #]
```

so it is working perfectly. Try evaluating

```
Hold@Map[If[# == 1, , #] &, {2, 1, 3, 1, 4}]
```

to see for yourself. To get what you want, try

```
Map[If[# == 1, Unevaluated@Sequence[], #] &, {2, 1, 3, 1, 4}]
```

Comment: thx, exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: Maybe mentioning `If[x > 1, , 2] // FullForm`, which evaluates to `If[Greater[x, 1], Null, 2]`, is also useful

Comment: Incidentally, `Unevaluated@Sequence[]` can be replaced with `##&[]` which I call a "vanishing function."

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. `##&[]` is a neat trick!