# How to use If to select arguments min & max in Range?

Tags: functions

I want to call `Range[]` with its arguments depending on a condition.  Say we have

```
checklength = {5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6}
```

I then want to call `Range[]` 13 times (the length of `checklength`) and do `Range[5]` when `checklength[[#]] == 5` and `Range[2, 6]` when `checklength[[#]] == 6`.  `If[]` would seem an appropriate way to do it,

```
Range[If[checklength[[#]] == 5, 5, XXX]]& /@ Range[13]
```

but I don't know what to put for "XXX", since I need "2,6" there without any brackets.  I've tried

```
Range[If[checklength[[#]]==5, 5, Flatten[{2,6}]]]& /@ Range[13]
```

but that doesn't help (in fact if you think about it, it shouldn't!).  The problem is, I need an unbracketed pair of numbers to be treated as a single argument and I don't know how to do that.  I can think of one quite messy solution,

```
Range[If[checklength[[#]] == 5, 1, 2], If[checklength[[#]] == 5, 5, 6]& /@ Range[13]
```

but I'd be disappointed if there's not a better way to do it.  Even though this does the trick, the general question remains of how to treat unbracketed comma separated numbers as a single item.

Comment: A way without using `If`: `checklength /. {5 -> Range@5, 6 -> Range[2, 6]}`

Comment: @rm-rf Well don't I feel silly. (Didn't see that.) +1 on the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution you are asking for is to pass the sequence of 2,6 which is nicely defined as `Sequence[2,6]` However if we simply put that as the last argument in `If`, it will be misinterpreted, for instance `If[False,Sequence[1,2]]` would return 2. So we need to use `Unevaluated`:

```
Range[If[checklength[[#]] == 5, 5, Unevaluated[Sequence[2, 6]]]] & /@ Range[13]
```

However in your particular case I would question why you are not instead simply using:

```
If[checklength[[#]] == 5, Range[5], Range[2, 6]] & /@ Range[13]
```

or:

```
If[# == 5, Range[5], Range[2, 6]] & /@ checklength
```

Which seems less convoluted to interpret and does what you need.

Comment: The use of If on the outside instead of the inside, as you've suggested, is far more straight forward.  Sometimes my brain picks a poor starting point and everything that follows is doomed!

Comment: Or perhaps `Range[# - 4, #] & /@ checklength`?

Comment: @MichaelE2. I did not see your comment.  I have deleted my answer.

Comment: No problem.  I don't mind either way.  I thought my comment was just a variation on jVincent's answer.

Answer (score 4):

For your "XXX" expression you need [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sequence.html) or an equivalent.  But since `If` does not have the attribute [`SequenceHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SequenceHold.html) it cannot appear explicitly as an argument of `If` or it will be flattened (inserted) prematurely.  This was covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8877324/618728) and later [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3447/121) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3700/121).

Therefore we may use `## &[2,6]` since the head of this expression is not `Sequence`:

```
## &[2, 6] // FullForm // HoldForm
```

> ```
> Function[SlotSequence[1]][2,6]
> ```

```
Range @ If[6 == 5, 5, ## &[2, 6]]
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
> ```

We could also use [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unevaluated.html) but there is no need to stack it on top of `Sequence` as it already evaluates to a Sequence expression.

```
Range @ If[6 == 5, 5, Unevaluated[2, 6]]
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
> ```

For your application it would IMO be simpler to use [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) instead and write:

```
Range @@ If[# == 5, {5}, {2, 6}] & /@ {5, 6}
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}
> ```

Observe that I am mapping across the equivalent of `checklength` directly.

Still better is to avoid this `If` construct entirely and use [replacement rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html).  Although `Range` is very fast and therefore the difference may not be significant this is also an order of magnitude faster on long lists than other general methods because the ranges are generated only *once* and then copied (thanks to the use of [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html) rather than [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html)).

```
{5, 5, 6} /. {5 -> Range[5], 6 -> Range[2, 6]}
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}
> ```

---

Note: You may notice red highlighting in the Front End in the expression `Unevaluated[2, 6]`; the multi-argument (and null-argument) form of `Unevaluated` is not documented but it is used internally by *Mathematica*.  You can adjust the highlighting to match by setting:

```
Unprotect[Unevaluated];
SyntaxInformation[Unevaluated] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {___}};
Protect[Unevaluated];
```

Comment: I added a couple of solutions.  They seem faster, but there's quite a variation between versions.  Would you please check on V7?  Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I confirm those are faster, but they're not general either, are they?  I mean what if the ranges were not conveniently offset?  Still I'll pull the wording from my answer.

Comment: That's true about about the generality with respect to replacement ranges offsets & lengths.  That might be worth pointing out explicitly.  There's something to be said for ease of understanding, too, and the replacement method was the first I thought of and the easiest to understand, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Even simpler than mapping or `Table`, since [`Range`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Range.html) is [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html):

```
Range[checklength - 4, checklength]
```

---

The above is elegant, but for the sake of speed, here's a faster one:

```
# + ConstantArray[Range[-4, 0], {Length@#}] &@ Developer`ToPackedArray @ checklist
```

yet this one is fastest:

```
Transpose @ Table[# + i, {i, -4, 0}] &@ Developer`ToPackedArray @ checklist
```

**Timings**

Comparing the
[rm-rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30305/how-to-use-if-to-select-arguments-min-max-in-range#comment94271_30305)/[Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30325) replacement method with the two above:

```
n = 10^6;
cl = RandomInteger[{5, 6}, {10, n}]; (* ten trials *)
{
  Do[
     # + ConstantArray[Range[-4, 0], {Length@#}] &@
      Developer`ToPackedArray @ cl[[seed]], {seed, 10}] // Timing // First,
  Do[
     Transpose@Table[# + i, {i, -4, 0}] &@
      Developer`ToPackedArray @ cl[[seed]], {seed, 10}] // Timing // First,
  Do[
     cl[[seed]] /. {5 -> Range[5], 6 -> Range[2, 6]}, {seed, 10}] // Timing // First
  } / 10
```

> ```
>          ConstantArray    Table     ReplaceAll
> V9.0.1  {  0.0629536,  0.0469905,   0.1893714 }
> V8.0.4  {  0.0297195,  0.0267913,   0.158208  }
> ```

Somewhat disappointing to see *Mma* slow down as it gets older.  (This holds over data sizes for `cl` from `10^2` to `10^7`.)

Comment: @TomD We were both just one character away from this: `Range[# - 4, #] &@ checklength` (`@` instead of `/@`). :)

Comment: Nice one.  Not a character of no importance :)

Answer (score 1):

Another straightforward approach is to just build the data using a `Table`. No `If` decisions required.

```
Table[Range[checklength[[i]] - 4, checklength[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[checklength]}]
```