# What does the slash-colon symbol do?

Tags: syntax, pattern-matching, documentation

I came across a bit of code that uses the syntax `/:` and I don't know what it does. I can't find its documentation, or maybe I'm just not looking properly. The code snippet is something like:

```
F/:F[A___,b_?NumberQ B_, C___] := b*F[A,B,C]
```

(i.e. part of the definition of multi-linearity). How does this behave differently than the following?:

```
G[A___,b_?NumberQ B_, C___] := b*G[A,B,C]
```

Thanks!

Comment: In the spirit of teaching people how to fish: highlight the `/:` part of the expression. Press F1. The help file should give links to the relevant functions.

Comment: Or at the very least, try entering `/:` into the doc center and see what comes up

Comment: Check `TagSet` in [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TagSet.html)

Comment: @J.M.,@R.M,@kguler: Thanks for the tips, I didn't know about the F1 thing. Having read those documentation pages, I still don't understand the difference between my two lines of code.

Comment: @IanHincks In this case, there is none. The docs mention that in the Scope section. For `OwnValues` (variables) and `DownValues` (functions), you can use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) with the same effect. But for `UpValues` (which are another kind of global rules), you need to use `TagSetDelayed` (`/:`), or perhaps `UpSetDelayed` (although I favor the former).

Comment: @IanHincks if you didn't know the F1 thing you have just learned one of the most important things in Mathematica

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, With the help of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues) post I was able to parse your comment and I now understand; thanks.

Comment: @Rojo it doesn't work on my MacBook (used to modify the screen brightness), so cmd-shift-f works instead.

Comment: @IanHincks I knew that question would come in handy! :)

Comment: I highly recommend also to read [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648260/what-does-upvalue-mean-in-mathematica-and-when-to-use-them)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`/:` is the short-hand notation for `TagSetDelayed`, which is creating `UpValues`.  It's useful for over-loading how a particular function behaves with a specific head.  For example:

```
In[1]:= h /: Plus[x : h[arg1_, arg2_], y : h[arg3_, arg4_]] := Plus[arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4]

In[2]:= h[1, 2] + h[3, 4]
Out[2]= 10
```

The benefit being you don't have to `Unprotect[Plus]` to set the definition, and if you `Remove[h]` this definition will be wiped out as well.

Comment: Thanks @nikko. What purpose do the `x` and `y` serve in this example? It seems to work without them.

Comment: @IanHincks in this example, they don't serve any purpose, but they could be used to refer to the entire object matched by `h[arg1_, arg2_]`. So, if you had need of the entire pattern, you could use it.

Comment: In this case, it is `TagSetDelayed` rather than `TagSet`. The syntax in fact has to parts: `s/:lhs:=rhs` or `s/:lhs=rhs`, so `/:` alone is not enough to tell which one it is. Also, a correct statement is that `TagSetDelayed` (or `TagSet`) *can* create `UpValues` (but it can also create `OwnValues`, `DownValues` and `SubValues`, in which case, the tag part is redundant).

Comment: yes, sorry the x: and y: are superfluous here.