# Nested If statements

Tags: functions, conditional

When I do this:

```
Apply[(If[#2 == what, "yay", If[#2 == whoops, "nay"]]) &, {-5, what}]
```

I get:

```
yay
```

But when I do this:

```
Apply[(If[#2 == what, "yay", If[#2 == whoops, "nay"]]) &, {-5, whoops}]
```

I get:

```
If[whoops == what, "yay", If[whoops == whoops, "nay"]]
```

This setup does work for numbers:

```
Apply[(If[#2 == 2, "yay", If[#2 == 3, "nay"]]) &, {-5, 3}]
nay
```

What I was trying to do was when I got stuck here was define a `VertexRenderingFunction` in a `GraphPlot`

```
VertexRenderingFunction -> ({White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#, {2, 1}], 
Black, Text[
 If[#2 == alpha1, "Alpha", 
  If[#2 == beta, "Beta", 
   If[#2 == alpha2, "Alpha", 
    If[#2 == gamma, "(70,55)", 
     If[#2 == delta, "(90,50)"]]]]], #1]} &)
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try TrueQ[#2==what], etc. or even ===. Or supply a third argument to `If`. See docs.

Comment: Cool. Thanks JxB. `TrueQ[]` worked but why was == working on the outside `If` and not on the inside `If`?

Comment: See my answer. It should work.

Comment: In similar circumstances you might want to investigate `Switch` and `Which`, which are both easier to manage than nested `If` statements.

Comment: Ok thanks Verbeia, I'll check them out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At issue is what is being returned by `Equals` (`==`). Since both `what` and `whoops` do not have values associated with them ([`OwnValues`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/52), in specific), `what == whoops` returns unevaluated. So, `If` cannot process it as either `True` or `False`, so it remains unevaluated. A way to correct this is to provide a third argument to `If`, the neither option:

```
Apply[(If[#2 == what, "yay", If[#2 == whoops, "nay"], "neither"]) &, {-5, what}]
Apply[(If[#2 == what, "yay", If[#2 == whoops, "nay"], "neither"]) &, {-5, whoops}]
(* 
 "yay"
 "neither"
*)
```

But, I do not believe you wish to use that form. There are three alternatives. First, you can provide values for `what` and `whoops`, then the `If` statement will then be processed. However, if you wish to use them as is, replace `Equals` with [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SameQ.html) (`===`),

```
Apply[(If[#2 === what, "yay", If[#2 === whoops, "nay"]]) &, {-5, what}]
Apply[(If[#2 === what, "yay", If[#2 === whoops, "nay"]]) &, {-5, whoops}]
(*
 "yay"
 "nay"
*)
```

or, as JxB suggest, use [`TrueQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TrueQ.html)

```
Apply[(If[TrueQ[#2 == what], "yay", If[TrueQ[#2 == whoops], "nay"]]) &, {-5, what}]
Apply[(If[TrueQ[#2 == what], "yay", If[TrueQ[#2 == whoops], "nay"]]) &, {-5, whoops}]
(*
 "yay"
 "nay"
*)
```

Either expresses your intent, but `SameQ` requires less typing although it is more difficult to see upon casual inspection.

Comment: awesome!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Verbeia's comment, it is probably easier to use `Which`, especially when you get to your Vertex rendering function, which has more nested Ifs. For the present case:

```
Which[#2 === what, "yay", #2 === whoops, "nay"] & @@ {-5, what}
```

returns "yay" or "nay" as desired.