# How do I show the combined plot from the do-loop?

Tags: plotting

I have a do-loop to do the calculations from a set of data and plot the graphs with different results, that was obtained from the calculations. I was able to get multiple graphs but I want to ListPlot the different graphs in one plot. Basically, I just want one graph by the end of do-loop plotting the results.

---

``` a = 0; b = 1;
Do[a++; b++;``t[a]; t[b]; ```

`Do[temp[i] = Transpose[t[i]]; counter[i] = temp[i][[1]]; 
  totaltime[i] = temp[i][[2]]; id[i] = temp[i][[3]];
  edge[i] = temp[i][[4]]; area[i] = temp[i][[5]], {i, a, b}];`

`VT = Table[Null, {i, 1, z}];    (*VT={reduced area with time}*)`

`Do[j = Flatten[Position[id[a], id[b][[i]]]][[1]]; 
  If[edge[b][[i]] == edge[a][[j]], 
   V = (area[b][[i]] - area[a][[j]])/scale; 
   VT[[i]] = {totaltime[a][[j]], V}], {i, 1, z}];`
  `minE = Min[edge[b]]; maxE = Max[edge[b]];`

`Table[T[i] = Take[VT], {i, 1, m - 1, 1}];
 Print[T[i]]
  Print[ListPlot[{T[i]}, Frame -> True,
    PlotRange -> {minE - 6 - 1, maxE - 6 + 1}, Axes -> False, 
    GridLines -> {None, Table[i, {i, minE - 6, maxE - 6}]}, 
    PlotLabel -> StringJoin["Interval = ", ToString[interval]]]]
 , {i, 1, m - 1, 1}]`

I have edited the code. I'm new to this so please forgive me for the mistakes. I know that ListPlot can plot multiple sets in one plot like"ListPlot[{data1,data2,...}, Frame -> True," However I have like hundreds of output data and that's where I can't seems to do. My code above gives multiple plots and I just want one output plot.

Comment: `ListPlot` can handle multiple data sets in form `{data1, data2`, ...}. Also, you can take a look at `Show`. Or I'm missing something but it's hard to tell since there is not much information in your question.

Comment: Welcome to *Mathematica*.SE! Please include code (best as minimum working example) and show us what you already tried, otherwise this Q&A will only be of very limited use for future visitors and might be closed.

Comment: Lithium, I assumed the anonymous edit to this post was yours and approved it, with added formatting.  I'm afraid it's still not clear what you want, at least to me.

Comment: Sorry, for not being clearer. I want to plot this 13 points at different time, Time Vs V. So I want to do this calculation 10 times and get 10 sets of Time Vs V. Then combine all in one graph. So I would have 10 set of V at 10 different times. The graph would show change of V with change of time. I'm trying my best to be clear. I hope that I'm . Thanks for helping.

Comment: The code you posted has several syntax errors. Could you post an updated version without such errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to long for a comment, and not a proper answer.

The primary disadvantage of using [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Do.html), [`For`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/For.html), and [`While`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/While.html) is they do not produce a return value. So, by using them, the user is forced into a c/c++ mode of thought where intermediate values are output to stdout (which is what [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$Output.html) effectively does), instead of using a form that produces results allowing further calculations to make use of them. The output `Print` does produce is usable in the same manner that the output of `printf` is. There are legitimate uses for these functions, like speed and compilability, but those should only be considered if the more [functional forms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/52) like `Table` and `Map` fail. In fact, you use `Table`, but only to create [`DownValues`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/52) for `T` which takes a speed hit.

Comment: I realized I could do without the table and still get the plots. Now I'm only working with a few hundreds data but I will have to do bigger scale and I don't want a lot of plots. If I don't use do-loop is there any other way?

Comment: Depending on your speed needs, `Table` should work just fine, but if you need to optimize things, look at `Array`, also.

Comment: thank you for your help.Using Table works.

Answer (score 6):

What makes your question hard to answer is that you have boxed yourself in by writing the code in such an awkward fashion -- hence you see an answer like Nasser's which has all those `Reaps` and `Sows`. Most likely, none of that is necessary. Let's take the heart of your question (which appears to be): "I want to do this calculation 10 times and get 10 sets of Time Vs V. The graph would show change of V with change of time."

What you should do (as hinted at by Kuba) is to make all the calculations (giving you 10 times 10 sets of data), give this a name, and then plot it at the end. For example, say your calculations give data

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10, 13}];
```

Of course this is just a surrogate for your calculated data (I can't understand the code you posted becaue it does not function, e.g., `Transpose[...,{i,a,b}]` is not a legal command). Now you can plot these 10 different data sets as a function of time:

```
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image]

If you do end up using the `Do` construction (and there are almost surely better ways to do this as well), at least pull the `Plot` commands from outside the main loop.

Comment: I get your answer but after "Do" construction, it only gives the last result and not all the data.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Sow` and `Reap`

```
r = First@Last@Reap@Do[
      Sow[Table[{i, RandomReal[1]}, {i, 10}]];
      Print[" iam working"];
      Sow[Table[{i, RandomReal[1]}, {i, 10}]];
      Print[" iam working"];
      Sow[Table[{i, RandomReal[1]}, {i, 10}]]
      , {2}];

Dimensions[r]
(* {6, 10, 2} *)
```

so there are 6 plots there, each has 10 rows and 2 columns

```
ListLinePlot[r, Joined -> True, Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `Mesh -> All` is neater, as it puts the mesh points on the data points.