# Finding Anagrams of given length from DictionaryLookup

Tags: string-manipulation, map, dictionary, curated-data

What I'm trying to find are the 4 letter words in the *Mathematica dictionary* that have the most anagrams and the amount of anagrams these have each.

But I can't seem to find all the 4 letter words in the Mathematica dictionary.  My output only results in 3-8 letter words.  Input is below

```
 wordperms =Flatten[Map[DictionaryLookup,Map[StringJoin, Permutations[Characters[#]]]]] &;
 words = DictionaryLookup[];
 sorted = Sort[Map[Sort, Map[Characters, words]]];
 Part[Select[Tally@sorted, Part[#, 2] > 4 &], All, 1];
 found = Part[Select[Tally@sorted, Part[#, 2] > 4 &], All, 1];
 Map[wordperms, found]
```

Answer (score 12):

This is an interesting puzzle. I think, though, you should restrict yourself to only words of length 4, to save processing time, as follows:

```
words = DictionaryLookup[Repeated[CharacterRange["a", "z"], {4}]];
```

where I used `CharacterRange` to eliminate proper names and contractions. This has the side effect that all accent marks, umlauts, etc. are also removed. As to creating the actual anagram list, my solution involves creating a hash table, of sorts.

```
ClearAll[anagrams];
SetAttributes[anagrams, Orderless];
anagrams[__] := {};
anagrams[s_String] := anagrams[Sequence @@ Characters[s]]
```

where these initial definitions of `anagrams` provides some helper code. To use this as a hash table, we need to feed in the words, as follows

```
(anagrams[Sequence @@ Characters[#]] = {#}~Join~anagrams[#]) & /@ words
```

It isn't the most elegant construction. For illustration sake, let

```
words = {"hat", "cat", "tac"}
```

then

```
DownValues@anagrams
(* 
{HoldPattern[anagrams["a", "c", "t"]] :> {"tac", "cat"}, 
 HoldPattern[anagrams["a", "h", "t"]] :> {"hat"}, 
 HoldPattern[anagrams[s_String]] :> anagrams[Sequence @@ Characters[s]], 
 HoldPattern[anagrams[__]] :> {}}
*)
```

So, after running it on the real set of `words`, we just need to extract the data:

```
data = Cases[DownValues@anagrams, 
 HoldPattern[Verbatim[HoldPattern][anagrams[a : Repeated[_, {4}]]] :> vals_] :> 
 {a} -> vals, Infinity];
```

and process it

```
Reverse[SortBy[data, Length@Last[#] &]][[;; 10]]
(*
{{"a", "e", "s", "t"} -> {"teas", "seat", "sate", "etas", "eats", "east", "ates"}, 
{"o", "p", "s", "t"} -> {"tops", "stop", "spot", "pots", "post", "opts"}, 
{"o", "s", "t", "w"} -> {"wost", "twos", "tows", "swot", "stow"}, 
{"a", "p", "r", "t"} -> {"trap", "tarp", "rapt", "prat", "part"}, 
{"a", "l", "s", "t"} -> {"slat", "salt", "lats", "last", "alts"}, 
{"a", "i", "l", "r"} -> {"rial", "rail", "lira", "liar", "lair"}, 
{"a", "e", "l", "s"} -> {"seal", "sale", "leas", "lase", "ales"}, 
{"i", "n", "p", "s"} -> {"spin", "snip", "pins", "nips"}, 
{"i", "k", "n", "s"} -> {"skin", "sink", "kins", "inks"}, 
{"h", "s", "t", "u"} -> {"tush", "thus", "shut", "huts"}}
*)
```

---

To make the process above a little less ad-hoc,

```
Clear[findAnagrams];
findAnagrams[words:{__String}]:=
Block[{anagrams, data},
 SetAttributes[anagrams, Orderless];
 anagrams[__] := {};
 anagrams[s_String] := anagrams[Sequence@@Characters[s]];
 (anagrams[Sequence@@Characters[#]] = {#}~Join~anagrams[#])& /@ words;
 Cases[DownValues@anagrams, 
    HoldPattern[Verbatim[HoldPattern][anagrams[a__String]]:> vals_]:> {a}-> vals, 
    Infinity]
]
```

Comment: I will have to reread this one over and over again since I'm not sure what a few functions mean, but I will look them up, thanks.

Comment: The answers to this [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/52) provide a good foundation for what `DownValues` and its siblings do.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do it using `GatherBy`:

```
GatherBy[DictionaryLookup[Repeated[_, {4}]], Composition[Sort, Characters, ToLowerCase]] /. 
    {_} -> Sequence[]
(* {{"abbe", "babe"}, {"Abby", "baby"}, {"abed", "bade", "bead"}, 
    {"Abel", "able", "bale", "Bela", "Elba"}, {"abet", "bate", "beat", "beta"}, 
    << big list >> *)
```

Of course, this also includes proper names, leading to duplicates such as `{"will", "Will"}` and several others, but it should be a trivial matter to weed them out.

Answer (score 4):

```
TakeWhile[Reverse@Map[StringJoin, 
  SortBy[GatherBy[DeleteDuplicates[ ToLowerCase[Characters[DictionaryLookup[x_ ~~ y_ ~~ z_ ~~ w_]]]],
                 Union], 
        Length], {2}],
 Length@# > 5 &]


(*

{{"ales", "elsa", "lase", "leas", "lesa", "sale", "seal"}, 
 {"ates", "east", "eats", "etas", "sate", "seat", "teas"}, 
 {"alts", "last", "lats", "lsat", "salt", "slat"}, 
 {"asap", "asps", "paps", "pass", "saps", "spas"}, 
 {"eels", "ells", "else", "lees", "less", "sell"}, 
 {"opts", "post", "pots", "spot", "stop", "tops"}, 
 {"sets", "sett", "stet", "tees", "tess", "test"}}

*)
```

Comment: I like this one, but if I did it this way, if I changed the 5 at the end, my nested list would continue to increase though.

Answer (score 2):

Idea from [this tweet](https://twitter.com/fermatslibrary/status/875340896379817984) by @fermatslibrary

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
char2primerule = Normal[
  Join[KeyMap[ToUpperCase, #], #] &@
     AssociationThread[#, Array[Prime, Length[#]]] &@
   CharacterRange["a", "z"]
  ]

word2product[s_String] := 
 Times @@ ReplaceAll[Characters[s], char2primerule]


anagrams[n_] := Select[
  GatherBy[
   DictionaryLookup[StringExpression @@ Table[LetterCharacter, {n}]]
   , word2product]
  , Length[#] > 1 &
  ]
```

---

Not related to that algorithm, but for completitude:

**To find an Anagram for a particular word**

```
anagramsto[s_String] := 
 DictionaryLookup[AnyOrder[Sequence @@ Characters[s]]
 , IgnoreCase -> True
 ]
```

or

```
anagramsto[s_String] := 
Module[{c = Sort[Characters[s]]},
 DictionaryLookup[x__ /; Sort[Characters[x]] == c]]
```