# Why are functions called first-class objects in Mathematica?

Tags: functions, evaluation, core-language

I've heard lots of people say a function is a first-class object in *Mathematica*. "Everything is an expression, including function." "There is no distinction between functions and data."

Having read the book *Power programming with Mathematica* up to Chapter 5, I think I already have some basic knowledge about *Mathematica*, but I'm still confused with this point.

To be more specific, I think there is a critical difference between functions and data. When we treat `f` as a function, we would use `f[3]` (**must use the brackets**); whereas to have `f` treated as a usual expression, we would simply use `f`. So I think a function (such as `f[x_] := x^2`) and data/expression (such as `f := x^2` or `f = 123`) are totally different! A function can accept several arguments, but a normal expression can not! "There's no difference between functions and data", is it real?

I also have another question (which has nothing to do with above). If we let symbol `f` have two characters "function" and "data(expression)" in the meantime, there will cause some problem.

1.

```
ClearAll[f]
f = 9
f[x_]:=x^2 (* message is printed *)
```

2.

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_]:= x^2
f = 9   (* MMA considers it is legal here *)
?f      ( *MMA shows the two definition of f above, but f is no longer 
          related to squaring something, as we can see below. *)
f[100]  (* this returns 9[100] *)
f       (* this returns 9 *)
```

Why is 2 OK, but not 1? In case 2, why does *Mathematica* not erase the definition of "function" f when we define `f = 9`? Furthermore, why does *Mathematica* allow the apparent error syntax `9[100]` without giving an error message? (We are very certain about numbers must not be a function name, the head of an normal expression!)

Comment: The `f = 9; f[x_]:=x^2` error since now the second line reads as `9[x_]:=x^2`

Comment: In case 2, why should it erase anything? `9[2]` is a perfectly valid expression with head 9. Case 1 results in a message for the same reason `9[2] = 3` does, ie, because `Integer` is protected. Try `Unprotect[Integer]; 9[2] = 3`.

Comment: The first part of your question may be answered by reading [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExpressionsOverview.html)

Comment: imo related: [DownValues, UpValues, SubValues, and OwnValues](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/5478)

Comment: @Kuba I think first one needs to realise that everything is an expression (a tree), then that mma does rewriting (in some possibly hard to understand way) with these expressions, and only then those answers will be useful. Otherwise it's like explaining contour integrals to someone who doesn't understand the abstract notion of a derivative (but can find the gradient using a ruler, for instance).

Comment: Try to parse the expression `x=(Sin + Cos)[a]` - are `Sin`/`Cos` values or functions here? They're added like values, after all. Is `Plus` a function? Since it is "called" with `[a]`. Now call `Through[x]`, and you'll get a perfectly sensible mathematical expression. Being able to manipulate expression trees like that is *extremely* useful.

Comment: You have an urgent need to read [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/3066) and its answers -- all its answers. You also have an urgent need to read Chapter 7 of Wagner's book.

Comment: I think that this statement might have had in mind "pure functions" like `(#^2)&` or `Function[x,(1+x)^3]`. These quite obviously are normal expressions **and** functions. "function definitions" like `f[x_]:=...` in Mathematica are actually definitions for global rewrite rules (as others have explained in more detail) which just happen to have an intuitive interpretation as functions but conceptually are not different from rules which e.g. define variable values.

Comment: I understand part 1 of my question now. One more question. `Clear[f, g];f = g;f[x_] = x^4`, I can understand the result of `?g`. However, why `{g,h,j}[[1]]=6` causes error? When using `=(Set)`, MMA first evaluate the first part `f` and `{g,h,j}[[1]]` to `g` and `g` right?(i.e. always evaluating lhs before assignment) Why is `f[x_] = x^4` ok, but not `{g,h,j}[[1]]=6`? I think the internal form of them are equivalent.

Comment: @Eric: You can use `Attributes[Set]` to find out which arguments are evaluated: It has the `HoldFirst` attribute, so the first argument isn't evaluated. You could write `Evaluate[{g, h, j}[[1]]] = 6`, though.

Comment: @Eric because it tries to set `Part[List[g, h, j], 1]` to `6`. Do `FullForm[Hold[{g, h, j}[[1]] = 6]]` to see that. This happens because `Set` has attribute `HolfFirst`, as nikie said.

Comment: but Clear[f, g];f = g;f[x_] = x^4 the lhs of the last statement evaluated(f->g, g[x_]=x^4, by checking ?g) before assignment, so I guess {g,h,j}[[1]] will first evaluted to g, then do the assignment `g=6`

Comment: er.. so what can we `Set` in general? It seemed setting `a={g,h,j}; a[[0]]=6` is ok. So set something to `expr` and `expr[i]` and `expr[[i]]` is ok, what else?

Comment: Also I noticed that `a={g,h,j}; a[[1]]=6` is OK, whereas `a[1]=6` is error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm guessing you're coming from a programming language where every expression must evaluate to a value, and if it didn't evaluate to something (like `5[Cos+Sin]`), it's a syntax error. To me, Mathematica started to make a lot more sense, once I stopped thinking about functions and values, and started to think of every expression as evaluating to an "expression tree". (Note to long-time Mathematica users: I'm trying to explain this form the point of view of someone coming from a different programming language. I'm glossing over a lot of details like `Set` vs `SetDelayed`, `Evaluate` and `Hold`, but the "conceptual model" I'm trying to explain here was very useful for me when I started with MMA.)

So, e.g. `a+b*c` yields an expression tree. You can use `TreeForm[a + b*c]` to display the actual tree:

[image]

The same is true for `a[b*c]`, or even `(b*c)[a]`. Think of these things as tree data structures, not as expressions as you might know them from C or Perl. For instance, you can access parts of that data structure using normal array-index syntax: `(a + b*c) [[2, 1]]` yields `b`. There are a few basic rules how operators can be combined, so e.g. `a+*b` or `x=[b]` are invalid, but other than that, you can build any tree you want.

The next step is that you can tell Mathematica tree manipulation rules that it should automatically apply to these trees. You could for example write:

```
a[x_ + c] := "Hello"
```

Now, any time Mathematica evaluates a tree that matches the pattern `a[x_ + c]`, it will replace it with "Hello". Don't think of this as a function declaration. Think of it as a replacement rule. And you can define almost *any* kind of pattern matching and replacement rule. For example, you could write the replacement rules:

```
(x_ + b)[y_] := x*y
z_ + c := 5 z
```

and Mathematica would from then on happily evaluate an expression like `(5+b)[6]` to 30 or `5+c` to 25.

(Note: Don't actually do this. It's a bad idea. In fact, it's such a bad idea that the people at Wolfram decided to protect the symbol `Plus` from being overwritten, to prevent you from doing this. But if you `Unprotect[Plus]`, you could actually do this.)

Also note, that when you define a "variable":

```
z := 10;
```

you're using *exactly* the same machinery. (Again, ignoring details like `DownValues` you can think of those as ugly performance improvement tricks.) This tells Mathematica to replace any expression tree that matches the pattern `z` by 10. We're calling some of these patterns "functions", other "variables", but to the Mathematica kernel, there's really no difference.

(You're maybe asking yourself now: Wait, I declare variables using `=`, not `:=`, right? In the cases above, you can actually use both, with the same results. `=` and `:=` are shorthands for `Set` and `SetDelayed`, respectively, which "register" a new pattern replacement rule with the Mathematica kernel. The only difference is that `Set` evaluates the second argument, while `SetDelayed` leaves it unevaluated.)

Here's another example, let's say you write:

```
Clear[x,f]
x = f[5]
```

This tells the Mathematica kernel that any expression that looks like `x` is to be replaced with `f[5]`. So if you enter `x+y` now, it evaluates to the expression tree `y+f[5]`. Mathematica doesn't care that `f` looks like a function to you and me - to Mathematica, this is just another old tree structure.

Now let's you set:

```
f[a_] := a*2
```

Again, this registers a new replacement rule. Now if we evaluate `x+y`, it (at first) evaluates to `y+f[5]`. But the kernel immediately notices that there's a replacement rule that matches `f[5]`, and replaces it, with `2*5`. So the expression evaluates to `10+y`.

You should *not* think of this as "variable `x` changed its value". `x` never changed its value, it's still set to the expression tree `f[5]`. You can `Clear[f]` and evaluate `x` again to check.

All this is a bit confusing when you're coming from a "conventional" programming language. But it is *extremely* useful for manipulating symbolic expressions. For example, with the knowledge you have now, you could probably write a function that takes the derivative of a basic arithmetic expression in about 10 lines. Try that in a conventional programming language!

Comment: Another strange-looking pattern that doesn't require altering `Plus` might be e.g. `(a_Integer)[b, x_] ^:= x + a`. Anyway, I think this answer is very good and should really help the OP; +1.

Comment: Good answer, also maybe [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExpressionsOverview.html) is useful (although I think using `TreeForm`, as you suggested, and thinking hard is probably the way to go).

Comment: @acl: The documentation is great once you get the computational model. But I must admit that I had a lot of trouble understanding it at first, when I started with all the (mis)conceptions about what expressions, functions and values are, coming from C++.

Comment: I completely agree, however, the part of the docs I linked to tries to explain how everything is an expression in mma. It even shows trees like you did, etc. Of course one needs to also realise that you can mentally model what mma does as transforming tree-like objects according to user- or system-specified patterns.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think I can smoothly parse the tree form of some expression like `a^2+b^c*d-(x+y)^k`. However, I still can't figure out why people always say "there is no distinction between function and data?" I think it is reasonable to say that "the definition of a function is (via) an expression", but when we want to define a function in MMA, we need to type `f[x_]:=...`, and calling it using `f[4]`. An expression(take "`x^2+2 x+1`" or "`a=x^2+2 x+1`"for example) is an expression; whereas a function(take "`f[x_]:=x^2+2 x+1`") is a function, their "essence" seem not same.

Comment: I can trust that "a function is defined by expression(e.g. `f[x_]:=x^2`, where x^2 is)." I can trust that "a function call is an expression(e.g. `Sin[3.6]`, where `Sin` is the head and the `3.6` is the part-1)." But it's hard for me to operate a function `f` arbitrary just like other ordinary expressions. After all, a function always needs to type with brackets(leave the symbol `f` alone is meaningless, or `2*f` is meaningless), but there is no need when typing ordinary expression. This is why I doubt "there's no distinction between functions and data(expression)."

Comment: @Eric: I didn't doubt that you can parse the expression tree. A C programmer can parse expression trees, too. The point is: The C programmer will rarely handle expression trees at runtime, unless she's writing a compiler. In Mathematica, you handle expression trees *all the time*.

Comment: @Eric You need to think about how evaluation happens in mma (eg ch 7 in Wagner).

Comment: Basically, think about it this way: what mma does is handle trees, and how it handles them is by applying rules to them. `f[x_]:=Sin[x]` defines a rule but is itself a tree. For example: `ReleaseHold@ReplaceAll[Hold[f[x_] := Sin[x]], Sin -> Cos]`, ie, you can manipulate the expression tree. It's true that it looks like there is a big difference between `f` and `f[x]`, and it looks like `f[x_]:=...` has been "executed" to define a function, but that's not true. cont'd

Comment: Look at the [answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues) Kuba mentioned to see what actually happens.

Comment: So final comment, see eg `f[x_] := Cos[x]; DownValues[f]`. `f` is still an expression, but to understand how this works you need to learn about `DownValues` and friends.

Comment: @Eric: I've added a new paragraph about how "variables" and "functions" are basically treated the same way.

Comment: @nikie maybe if you show how `f[x_]:=Sin[x]` isn't stored in some special way it will help. That seems to be the misunderstanding (ie, that `f[x_]:=Sin[x]` does something special that's fundamentally different from `f=3`. Or anyway that's what it looks like.

Comment: Having read the links and the explanation you(@acl, @nikie, @Kuba, @albert, @m_goldberg and so on) gave, I think what I used to think of the "function" in MMA is wrong. I state my new understanding of function in MMA here, and still appreciate your help. :)

First it seems that there are no truly "function" semantics in MMA. There're only(?) term-rewriting systems. If one wants to implement "functions" like in math or other languages, he should use term-rewriting system. i.e. binding a rule to a symbol, e.g. `father[child_]:=child^2`. In the view of tree form, it is equivalent to think

Comment: whenever encounters a symbol `father` which has exactly one child, then rewrites this symbol(and it's child) to `child^2`. So it is absolutely reasonable to see one may write the code like `father+father`, `2*Sin[father]^4 /.father -> Pi`, because `father` is undoubtedly an ordinary symbol!

Comment: Hope this understanding or viewpoint is 100% correct.

Comment: @Eric I think that's right

Comment: PS: I was new to stackexchange in 2014, so I wasn't aware of there was an answer-accepting mechanism. Now I have chosen this to be the accepted answer. Thanks to the people who helped me before. :)

Answer (score 5):

When you use the syntax `f[x_]:= ...` in Mathematica, you are not defining a function `f`.
You are defining a pattern-replacement rule.
The documentation and the users tend to be vague or misleading or just incorrect about this point.  Of course you can define "function" as something quite to your liking and ignore the protestations of mathematicians, "functional programming" fans etc.

Here is an actual function definition in Mathematica.

`f = #^2&`

in `FullForm` it looks like this:

`Function[Power[Slot[1],2]]`

You can apply the function f in the usual way, e.g. `f[5]`  returns `25`.

How does this differ from what you might write,   `f[x_]:=x^2` ?

Consider this as a function ...

```
g[x_Integer]:= x^2;
g[x_Real]:=x^3
```

and you see it is not really a function but a set of two rules.

Now what does it meant to say that functions are first class objects?

You can use f in various ways that might not be legal in other languages.
You can pass `f` as an argument to a function.   You can use it in expressions.
For example, `Sin[f]`.  Not that it necessarily makes sense, but it is not
illegal.

Since what you probably meant by Function  is in Mathematica terminology a Rule,
you might ask, is a Rule a first class object.  Yes.  Is the rule set that is
associated with a name like `g`, above, a first class object, probably not, though
this following example may play more with Mathematica's bindings than you find
comfortable.  Using the above definition of g..

```
test[fun_, k_] := Block[{g = Print[nope] &} , fun[k]]
```

now `test[g,3]`  returns  / prints    `nope`.

Answer (score 3):

The OP asks in a comment:

> One more question. Clear[f, g];f = g;f[x_] = x^4, I can understand the result of ?g. However, why {g,h,j}[[1]]=6 causes error? When using =(Set), MMA first evaluate the first part f and {g,h,j}[[1]] to g and g right?(i.e. always evaluating lhs before assignment) Why is f[x_] = x^4 ok, but not {g,h,j}[[1]]=6?

The OP indicates that he now understands standard evaluation, but it would seem that he has yet to grasp non-standard evaluation. Because it has the `HoldFirst` attribute, `Set` can and does non-standard evaluation of its first argument. It expects its unevaluated first argument to be a symbol. The reason for this is that `Set` has side-effects. It changes the binding of the unevaluated symbol passed into it.

Consider

```
a = {g, h, j}; a[[1]] = 6; a
```

> ```
> {6, h, j}
> ```

The above code not only rewrites the list `{g, h, j}` to `{6, h, j}`, it also changes the binding of `a`; it has no effect on `g`. In this code, `g` is just a placeholder.

The code

```
{g, h, j}[[1]] = 6
```

doesn't work because, although `Set` can rewrite the list `{g, h, j}` to `{6, h, j}`, it doesn't have a symbol to bind to the rewritten list. So it can't accomplish its side effect, forcing it to print a message and fail.

Note that as part of its non-standard evaluation, `Set` must recognize when its first argument is bound to a `Part` expression and treat it differently. In such a case, it must rewrite the list appropriately (maybe using `ReplacePart`) rather the making the simple rebinding it does with symbol bound to,say, an atom.

Comment: er...   Clear[a, f, g, h, i]; (a = {g, h, j}; a[[1]] = 6)
    Clear[a, f, g, h, i]; {g, h, j}[[1]] = 6
the fourth line is wrong, but I didn't find any difference  between it and the second line..

Comment: Or be simple, I just didn't understand the description " _...doesn't work because, although Set can rewrite the list {g, h, j} to {6, h, j}, it doesn't have a symbol to bind to the rewritten list. So it can't accomplish its side effect, forcing it to print a message and fail._"

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. `a = {g, h, j}; a[[1]] = 6; a` works fine for me. `{g, h, j}[[1]] = 6` can never work for the reasons I gave in my answer. What symbol do you think `Set` will rebind in latter expression?

Comment: I think `a[[1]] = 6` is assigning `6` to `Part[a,1]`(whole term have been hold by `=`), where `Part[a,1]` is seemingly meaningless(tended to arise wrong). (because `Part[a,1]` is not a clean or "single" symbol just like something like `a`)

Comment: So claim something like `a[[1]] = 1000` is also under a pattern matching? i.e. just like defining `f[x_]:=x^2`, `a[[1]]=1000` means whenever encounters symbol `a` which has children, then the first child of `a` is always replaced to `1000`?

Comment: `a[[1]] = 6` makes a copy of the list `a` is bound to, inserts 6 into slot 1 of the copy, and then rebinds `a` to the copy. The rebinding is done by creating a new delayed rule `{HoldPattern[a] :> {6, h, j}}` in the own-values of `a`. Evaluate `OwnValues[a]` after evaluating `a[[1]] = 6` to see it. This can't be done when `Set` is given `{g, h, j}[[1]] = 6` because there no symbol, no `a`, with a down-value list to modify.

Comment: still can't understand with _a[[1]] = 6 makes a copy of the list a is bound to, inserts 6 into slot 1 of the copy, and then rebinds a to the copy._ Could you please give me a step by step (with code) explanation? I wanted to use `TracePrint`, but there was nothing. Or do I have to be very familiar with the mechanism of pattern matching in advanced? (I think the problem is more related to the order of evaluation then how pattern matching works.)If so, I'll read them first.

Comment: I think the statement "`{g,h,j}[[1]] = 6` can never work" is not correct. As `Set` has `HoldFirst` it would very well be able to extract the (held) symbol `g` and change its `OwnValues`, just as it is able to do in something like `{g,h}={1,2}`. Unlike the latter the former has not been implemented, probably for good reasons, probably just because nobody at WRI bothered about that specific case...

Comment: @AlbertRetey I'm very confused about what can we `Set` in general? `Set` something like `3=9` is meaningless, thus I can first be sure the lhs of `=` should be symbol-like things. By the way, it seemed OK to set `a=9` or `a={g,h,j}; a[[1]]=6`. If we want to summarize, setting something to `expr` and `expr[i]` and `expr[[i]]` are OK, what else? The official document didn't list all the things that can be the lhs of `Set`.

Comment: @Eric: as has been explained the "miracle" of `Set` is that it has the `HoldFirst` attribute. This will make `Set` see the unevaluated LHS. What the code within `Set` does with that unev. LHS is up to the programmers at WRI who wrote that code. Obviously it does analyze that LHS-expr. and for some special cases does "the right thing". There is nothing to be understood at the language level here, it really is just an implementation detail which even could change between versions. Unfortunately the documentation of what such functions actually implement is often somewhat vague or incomplete...

Comment: @Eric: one more remark about `3=9`: for a term rewriting system this might not be that meaningless at all, e.g. it would work perfectly well in a local replace rule: `(a+3) /. {3->9}`. As far as I understand, the only reason why defining such a rule globally with `Set` wouldn't work is that Mathematica demands a global replace rule to be attached to a symbol, which in this case isn't possible as the LHS is just an atomic integer ...

Comment: @m_goldberg can you explain what you mean by `bind` and `rebind` in this context?

Comment: @anhnha. "bind" means to form an association between an identifier and a value object, so that, when the identifier is recognized in an expression by the evaluator, the value object will replace the identifier. "rebind" means to change the current association of identifier to a new value object.

Comment: @m_goldberg thank you. How do you know that `rebind` will happen in your post? 
Is there anywhere I can read more about this?

Comment: @anhnha. I know it happens because 1) I observe it as a side effect of `Set` and 2) it is made clear in the documentation that rebinding is one the main reasons `Set` exists in the Wolfram Language. You can learn more on [this page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/). There are a couple of articles on `Set` on the page. It's a big page and you may find it useful to make a local search on `Set`.