# Why does the documentation call functions "pure"?

Tags: functions, evaluation, pure-function

Clearly, `Function`s in mathematica are not pure functions according to [the definition on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) (no side effects - basically implementabe with table lookups)

> 1. the function return values are identical for identical arguments (no variation with local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or input streams), and
> 2. the function application has no side effects (no mutation of local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or input/output streams).

Consider:

```
x = 4;
y = 1;
a = Function[y = 0; x + #];

y (*== 1*)
a[5] (*== 9*)
y (*== 0*)

x = 0;
a[5] (*== 5*)
```

this produces

> ```
> {1, 9, 0, 5}
> ```

Clearly it is affected by external changes (violating 1.) and it does have side-effects (violating 2.).
Yet the manual keeps referring to functions as "pure functions" (c.f. e.g. "tutorial/PureFunctions" or [How to | Work with Pure Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithPureFunctions.html)).

> The most transparent way to define a pure function is with Function.

What's the deal with this unnecessary and wrong wordiness? "Function" would have done fine...

Comment: Mathematics definition of pure function is completely different.  "Pure functions allow you to give functions which can be applied to arguments, without having to define explicit names for the functions.  ".  Maybe that wiki pages needs an 'alternate uses' section.

Comment: To expand on George's comment, a pure function in _Mathematica_ does not describe a transformation rule where as any use of `=` or `:=` associates a transformation rule with the symbol on the LHS, e.g. `OwnValues`, `DownValues`, `SubValues`, [etc](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/52). So, in that sense, it is pure.

Comment: Clearly, this is a NKPF.

Comment: Mathematica pure functions really should be called anonymous functions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function  Java now has them, called there as lambda functions. C++ 11 has them also. The name "pure" is overloaded a little. The main thing is "is a function definition that is not bound to an identifier" from the above Wiki

Comment: @Nasser, I think your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: @Nasser wow, I had to learn about `#0` from wikipedia.

Comment: Interestingly, the tooltip for the tag `pure-function` here on MM.SE says "Questions about implementing or applying functions which: (1) always yield the same result for the same input, (2) are independent of outside information, and (3) produce no side effects." which is again not the Mathematica definition

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The term *pure function* used in *Mathematica* is not being used in the same sense as the cited Wikipedia article.  In *Mathematica* it refers to an anonymous function.  In the Wikipedia article it is a term extracted by analogy from the increasingly popular term "purely functional" which refers (mainly) to deterministic programming free of side-effects.

The *Mathematica* usage largely predates the contemporary popular usage.

**Pure Function in *Mathematica***

[Section 4.1.4](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v1/contents/4.1.4.pdf) of the *Mathematica Book* (1988), states:

> There are various ways to specify the functions you give as arguments.  If they are built-in functions, or are functions that you have explicitly defined, then you can refer to them simply by giving their names.  In many cases, however, it is more convenient to be able to build up "pure functions" to which you do not have to give specific names.

This usage aligns with what are often called "anonymous functions" today.  Note the use of quotation marks around "pure functions" suggesting that the term is being coined here.  Later, it is said that:

> This kind of *Mathematica* expression is directly analogous to the λ expressions that are used in LISP or in formal logic.

Again, this emphasizes their usage as anonymous functions.  And then:

> One goal of functional programming is completely to eliminate named variables.

So, in *Mathematica*, it appears that the "purity" of a function means that is it unencumbered by names.  (I note in passing that *eliminate named variables* suggests the [point-free programming style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) to me.  Slots in pure functions do not conform to that style, but V10 is adding features that make point-free style a little easier.)

**Pure Function in Wikipedia**

The cited Wikipedia article defining the term "pure function" is tagged as controversial for lack of supporting citations.  Neither of the [two](http://it.bmc.uu.se/andlov/dev/books/haskell98-report.pdf) [references](http://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/currywiki/) that it cites define, or even mention, the term "pure function".

They do, however, speak of "pure functional" or "purely functional" programming languages.  I suspect that "pure function" in that article is simply a coined reduction of the far more widespread term "purely functional".

**Purely Functional in Popular Usage**

My own impression is that the "pure" qualifier with respect to functional programming was relatively obscure until the Haskell programming language started to get some mindshare.  Haskell emerged from the pure functional programming community in 1990, two years after *The Mathematica Book*, and even then did not really gain popularity until after the release of Haskell98.

I find it interesting to note that the following papers make no use of the term "pure" in connection with functional programming:

- John Backus (1977), [Can Programming Be Liberated from the von Neumann Style? A Functional Style and Its Algebra of Programs](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs242/readings/backus.pdf)
- M. Gordon, R.Milner (1978) [A Metalanguage for Interactive Proof in LCF*](http://www-public.it-sudparis.eu/~gibson/Teaching/CSC4504/ReadingMaterial/GordonMMNW78.pdf)
- R.M. Burstall, et al (1980) [HOPE: An Experimental Applicative Language](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.18.8135)
- Philip Wadler (1986), [A critique of Abelson and Sussman -or- Why Calculating is better than Scheming](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/wadler87.pdf)
- John Hughes (1990) [Why Functional Programming Matters](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/whyfp90.pdf)

But we start to see usage of the term by the time of these:

- David Turner (1986), [An Overview of Miranda](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/Overview.html)
- Paul Hudak, Philip Wadler, et al (1990), [Report on the Programming Language Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell-report-1.0.ps.gz)
- Philip Wadler (1992), [Comprehending Monads](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/WadlerMonads.pdf)

If the Google books [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=purely%20functional%20programming%2Cpure%20functional%20programming&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpurely%20functional%20programming%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpure%20functional%20programming%3B%2Cc0) is to be believed, then the *Mathematica* usage of "pure" appears at the leading edge of an upsurge in wider usage:

[image: ngram viewer screenshot]

**Summary**

I interpret this (admittedly anecdotal) evidence to support the position that the *Mathematica* use of "pure function" is not a misapplication of the general usage.  Rather, it is an independently coined term for "anonymous function" that predates the contemporary common understanding.