# What's the meaning of #0?

Tags: pure-function

Here's a line of code from a handbook written by Stephen Wolfram, which turns out to be very complicated for me.

---

`If[#1 > 2, 2 #0[#1 - #0[#1 - 2]], 1] & /@ Range[50]`

---

The output is:

```
{1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 8, 16, 4, 2, 16, 4, 2, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 8, 16, 4, 8, 16, 16, 8, 4, 16, 32, 4, 4, 32, 64, 4, 2, 64, 4, 2, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 8, 16, 4}
```

I am confused about the Slot 0(#0) here, or how could I break down the code and understand it?

Comment: [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96220/is-it-possible-to-reference-self-from-a-pure-function) is a dedicated Q/A on this topic.

Comment: This is discussed in the documentation for `[`Slot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`#0` refers to the function itself. This is consistent with the "0th" argument being the head of an expression.

Example:

```
Print[#0] &[]

(* prints Print[#0]& *)
```

In practice, this is useful for writing recursive functions. This is what it is used for in your example.  The example could be rephrased as

```
f[x_] := If[x > 2, 2 f[x - f[x - 2]], 1]
```

Comment: I'm going to have to remember this trick the next time I'm over on [PCG Stackexchange.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The problem is that we still need to add a stopping condition for the recursion, and with this method it needs to be done with an `If[...]`. That will sometimes make the code longer than the pattern matching version.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Well, actually a Fibonacci *is* shorter with the pure function method: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg38W.png