# Constructing a List of Functions

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

I would like to construct a list of Functions that can be used like: 
`F[z][[i]]`

Where one can choose between list elements with `i` and that the function evaluates at the point `z`. So that one can have either a List of Functions when `z` is declared or a List of Values when `z` has a particular value.

I tried to do it like:

```
n = 10;
t[z_] := 0.58 ( 1 - 0.02624 Power[ Abs[z]/500, 2.2306]);
c[z_] := t[z] - t[0];
R1[z_] := 125 + t[z] + c[z];
RList = {Function[z, R1[z]]};
Do[AppendTo[RList, RList[[i]] + Function[z, t[z] + c[z]] ], {i,n-1}];
```

Comment: Your problems are manifold. This is not a list. It is a sum. `AppendTo` works that way. But You misuse `Function`. The example from the Mathematica documentation for `Function` is `f = (3 + #) &` and `{f[a], f[b]}` with the result `{3 + a, 3 + b}`. Pure functions are the path to success for such kind of operation. Best luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you maybe give a small example for a solution? I've read through the Pure Function Tutorial but I don't quiet get how it fits to my problem.

Comment: Perhaps a nice example with an explanation is [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85750/memoization-with-pure-functions/85762#85762].

Comment: This question seems of bigger importance for Your forthcoming: [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56504/v10s-operator-forms-what-are-they-good-for]: get the `Function` to the standard introduced in V10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general case:
I can mention some patterns with different interfaces. Just a small example.
`f1` is just a list of functions. `f2` is a vector valued function. `f3` is like `f2`, but encapsulates the indexing as function parameter.

```
f1 = Table[With[{nn = n}, Function[x, x^nn]], {n, 1, 5}]
f1[[2]][x]

f2 = Function[{x}, Table[x^n, {n, 1, 5}] // Evaluate]
f2[x][[2]]

f3 = Function[{i, x}, Indexed[Table[x^n, {n, 1, 5}], i] // Evaluate]
f3[2, x]
```

For your special purpose:

```
n = 10;
t[z_] := 0.58 (1 - 0.02624 Power[Abs[z]/500, 2.2306]);
c[z_] := t[z] - t[0];
R1[z_] := 125 + t[z] + c[z];
RList = {Function[z, R1[z] // Evaluate]};
Do[AppendTo[RList, Function[z, RList[[i]][z] + t[z] + c[z] // Evaluate]], {i, n - 1}];
```

You need to use Function outermost of your list element and insert `z` everywhere it must be inserted, so resolving all inner `Function` objects.

It's a quick and dirty way. Maybe it can be done more efficently with `NestList` or something similar.

Comment: Exactly what I meant. Thank you!