# why does Function have the HoldAll attribute?

Tags: functions, core-language, language-design

Consider the following:

```
f = 2 # &
OwnValues[f]
g = f[#]/2 &
OwnValues[g]
```

Since `Function` has the `HoldAll` attribute, `g` expresses its own value in terms of `f` instead of in terms of the own value of `f`.  This obviously matters, because if I change `f` then `g` will change.  Doesn't this conflict with the lambda calculus motivation of `Function`, making WL's "pure' functions even more impure (from a functional programming perspective)?  Finally, in this case, is there a preferred way to force the definition of `g` to be in terms of the own values of `f`?  I suppose `g = Evaluate[f[[1]]/2] &` is possible ...

Comment: Without it in case of simplest functions like `Function[x, x ]` you would have to keep track whether `x` doesn't have a value outside.

Comment: I guess the first part answers itself, together with http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64577/why-does-the-documentation-call-functions-pure . FP-style 'pure' functions have nothing to do with 'Function' seems to be the bottom line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first question is a bit abstruse for me so I'd like to leave it to someone more knowledgeable. As to the second question,

```
g = f[[1]]/2 & /. OwnValues[f]
g = With[{f = f}, f[[1]]/2 &]
```

are 2 common ways to handle the issue.

Comment: Use of `With` seems to be exactly what I was looking for.  It avoids the problems that arise trying to use `Evaluate`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Because it couldn't possibly work if it weren't `HoldAll` ... There's so much code which is just plain invalid unless the argument is substituted in.

What about e.g.

```
Plus@@Table[i, {i, #}]&
```

?  Just try what happens if you remove the `&` and let the innards evaluate.

It goes wrong in multiple ways.

```
In[1]:= Plus @@ Table[i, {i, #}]

During evaluation of In[1]:= Table::iterb: Iterator {i,#1} does not have appropriate bounds.

Out[1]= {2 i, i + #1}
```

Just about any function except for ones defined as trivial formulae would break.

Plus, the effect of `HoldAll` can always be cancelled with a simple [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html).

```
In[2]:= f = 2 # &
Out[2]= 2 #1 &

In[3]:= g = Evaluate[f[#]/2] &
Out[3]= #1 &
```

Comment: I'm not understanding this response, because `Table` and `Plus` do not have own values.  Maybe I asked the wrong way, but the core of my question is why it is desirable to "break" the substitution of own values for a symbol (thereby introducing perhaps unexpected global dependencies).  I accept that your proposed use of `Evaluate` addresses the problem in my simple example.

Comment: @Alan There is some mismatch in our understanding of the issues involved because I also don't understand your comment.  It has not relevance to evaluation whether a transformation rule is an OwnValues, DownValue, or something else. Either *all transformations* are applied, or none of them (with `HoldAll`).  It's not possible to cherry pick what transformation is performed based on the type of "\*Value" involved.

Comment: My unfortunate specificity relates only to the example I provided (which only generates own values).  But it is also the case that `Table` and `Plus` have no up values or down values.
I think you are saying that there is no way to have a mechanism that would rewrite `f` in my example without doing something unfortunate in your example: either the argument is evaluated, or it is held.  I suppose you are just saying that I seem to want a half-way measure, but there are none when it comes to evaluation.  I recognize that the design decision is itself a good clue that you are correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Alan Why are you saying that those functions have no DownValues?

Comment: @sebhofer Because none are listed by the `DownValues` command.  I deduce from your question that I misrepresented something here.  No surprise: I'm a relative newbie.

Comment: @Alan Built-ins like `Table` have "internal/built-in `DownValues`" that are not listed by said command (and are always tried after user defined rules, c.f. tutorial/Evaluation).

Comment: @masterxilo That makes sense.  I was not sure how to refer to such builtin rules.  The tutorial you cite just calls them "built‐in transformation rules".

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Szabolcs answer and the discussion in the comments, here's another solution:

```
EvaluateOwnValuesOnlyAndHold~SetAttributes~HoldAll
EvaluateOwnValuesOnlyAndHold[expr_] := 
 Hold[expr] /. 
  x_Symbol /; AtomQ@Unevaluated@x(*don't capture Symbol["name"]*):> 
   With[{y = x}, y /; True](*force evaluation of x -- do we call *this* 'Villegas-Gayley' too?*)
```

Now we get e.g.

```
delta = 1;
Function @@ 
 EvaluateOwnValuesOnlyAndHold[Plus @@ Table[i, {i, #, delta}]]
```

> `Plus @@ Table[i, {i, #1, 1}] &`

and as desired:

```
f = 2 # &;
g = Function @@ EvaluateOwnValuesOnlyAndHold[
    f[#]/2
    ];
OwnValues[g]
g@42
```

> `{HoldPattern[g] :> (1/2 (2 #1 &)[#1] &)}`
>
> `42`

Comment: Note possible problems with scoping constructs e.g.: `i = 5; EvaluateOwnValuesOnlyAndHold[{i, Module[{i = 6}, i]}]`

Comment: "... do we call *this* 'Villegas-Gayley' too?" It's usually called [Trott-Strzebonski in-place evaluation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29318/14303)