# How to join the lhs and rhs of the rows of a matrix equation and solve for one of the variables?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, linear-algebra, vector, coefficients

The matrix equation `m.{x,y}==b` results in an awkward disjointed looking presentation but correct construction of a system of linear equations `{x + y, -x + y} == {1, 2}`.

- How do I put the results of `m.{x,y}==b` in a more proper form such
  as `eqs={x+y==1,-x+y==2}`.
- How to solve `eqs={x+y==1,-x+y==2}` for y    in terms of x so that
  the outcome looks like this:    `eqs={y==1-x,y==2+x}`?

Here is the working code...

```
ClearAll[m,b,vars,x,y,eqs];
m = {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}};
b = {1, 2};
vars={x,y};
eqs = m.vars == b;
```

Comment: For the first part, do this `eqs = Thread[m.vars == b]`.  For the second part, this is one way:  `Flatten[Solve[#, y] & /@ eqs] /. Rule -> Equal`

Comment: @LouisB Thank you for your help. By the way I had just figured out how to do first part and it is the same as your solution. Who knew `Thread` was the key and so easy? But I definitely appreciate the second part. Thanks again.

Comment: @LouisB what does this translate to `/@`? What I mean what is the name of that operator.? How would the second part look if written in `StandardForm` where all operators and functions are expressed without shortcuts? I wish to examine it closely so I could learn from it.

Comment: `/@` is a shortcut to the `Map` function.  The idea is to map the `Solve` function onto each equation in `eqs`.  Since `Solve` takes more than one argument, we create a pure function using & (`Function`) with # (`Slot`) to indicate the argument of the pure function.  Click on the symbol in the front-end and press F1 to get the help page for the symbol.  The documentation for  [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html)  has many useful examples.  Also see [Why use pure functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164597/why-use-pure-functions)

Comment: @JulesManson If you type `/@` in the documentation browser it will take you to the right function. This is very helpful as well for other mysterious glyphs like `@*`, `/*` and `@@@`. You can also use `FullForm[Hold[f /@ x]]` to see what `/@` is short for.