# Can Wolfram Language enforce pure functions?

Tags: pure-function

Is there a feature in Wolfram Language that supports or enforces [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)? WL has something that it calls ["pure functions"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) in its documentation, but these are most emphatically not pure functions. For example, something like

```
z=0;
Map[{#, Print[z=z+#];z}&, Range[5]]
```

has side effects and modifies its environment.

Does Wolfram Language have a way of ensuring that a function is in fact pure?

Comment: And as an aside: why does the documentation use "pure function" in the way that it does?

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is "no". Maybe you meant to ask "_Can_ Wolfram Language enforce pure functions?"

Comment: Towards your question in the comment: "Pure function" is used for `Function`s just to distinct them from "functions" defined by 'f[x_]:= ...`. However, the latter does not define a function, but a replacement rule.

Comment: related: [Why does the documentation call functions "pure"?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64577/142)

Comment: @WReach That's a good reference (which I missed). I'm definitely coming from the Haskell world, which explains why the Mathematica use grates. But I didn't realize that the history was the other way round! (It remains a legitimate question though why Wolfram continues this usage, and doesn't switch to the clearer "anonymous function".)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Fixed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the documentation call functions "pure"?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64577/why-does-the-documentation-call-functions-pure)

Comment: @MarcoB See previous comments: it answers my side question.

Comment: @MarcoB And it is precisely because of this that the answer to my question is _not_ "easily found in the documentation", and stands.