# for loop and list

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm new to *Mathematica*. I want to built a function like that;

```
DeltaA1[PavP_,t1_,Jp_,A0_,tau1_,tau2] := AbsorbanceA1[0,t1,Jp,A0,tau1,tau2] - 
  AbsorbanceA1[PavP,t1,Jp,A0,tau1,tau2]
```

all of the `t1`,`Jp` etc are constants and they were defined. Only `PavP` is a list of 10 numbers. So want to do this calculation for ten times. I wrote this for loop, maybe I'm missing something.

```
For[j = 1, j <= Length[PavP], j++, 
 TdeltaA[PavP[[j_]], t1_, Jp_, A0_, tau1_, tau2_] := 
  AbsorbanceA1[0, t1, Jp, A0, tau1, tau2] - 
   AbsorbanceA1[PavP[[j]], t1, Jp, A0, tau1, tau2]]
```

Comment: Take a look at `Map` and `Table` instead :)

Comment: Also look at the difference between `Set` (`=`) and `SetDelayed` (`:=`)

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. In your first definition the underscore is missing after tau2. In the loop you seem to want to define 10 functions, but in this case j in PavP[[j_]] should *not* have an underscore. Anyway, I don't see the necessity for defining 10 functions here. Just introduce a variable for the first position in the function and call the function with Pavp[[relevant value]] in the first position when needed.

Comment: Maybe combine the above mentioned `Map` with an overload like `Delta[Pav_?ListQ,...]:=Delta[#,...]&\@Pav` and `Delta[Pav_?NumberQ,...]:=Absorbance[...]`

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you wish to calculate `TdeltaA` for all of the values of `PavP` at whatever the other constants are set to. If so, then there is a lot here that is incorrect. First of all, statements of the form

```
f[x_] := x^2
```

define a function, or more correctly a transformation rule. The left-hand side is a pattern that the execution engine matches. For example, from above, `f[2]` would return `4`, `f[a]` would return `a^2`, but `f[3, 4]` would return `f[3,4]` because no rule has been set up for a two argument form of `f`.

Second, as pointed out in the comments, there is a difference between `:=` ([`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)) and `=` ([`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)). `Set` will evaluate the right-hand side before registering the pattern, while `SetDelayed` does so after the pattern is matched.  For example,

```
a = 5;
g[x_] = x^2 - a^2;
h[x_] := x^2 - a^2;
h[5] == g[5]
(* True *)
```

But, `h` is susceptible to changes in `a`:

```
a = 6;
h[5]
(* -11 *)
```

while `g` is not

```
g[5]
(* 0 *)
```

For a more complete explanation, you should look up [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) and [`OwnValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues.html), and [how they relate to each other](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/52).

Thirdly, the patterns on the left-hand side set up local variables on the right hand side in the function definition. If `Set` is used (not that I recommend it here), then right hand side is evaluated before the variables become localized. (They are localized on the left-hand side, though.) This means any global values would be used, if they existed. For example,

```
x = 5;
q[x_] = x^2 - a^2
(* - 11 *)

q[28]
(* -11 *)
```

the value of `q` is fixed.  But, with `SetDelayed`, the named patterns (`x` in `f`, `g`, `h`, and `q`) become localized, and do not take on global values.  For example, this

```
r[x_] := x^2 - a^2
```

acts identically to `h`, above, despite `x` having a global value.

To wrap up, what you are doing is creating a function, not a list of values, which is what I suspect you want. The `For` loop, in fact, is just overwriting the definition a bunch of times, and not generating anything useful. To generate your list, I would do the following:

```
DeltaA1 = AbsorbanceA1[0,t1,Jp,A0,tau1,tau2] - 
 AbsorbanceA1[#,t1,Jp,A0,tau1,tau2]& /@ PavP
```

which evaluates (see [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html))

```
AbsorbanceA1[0,t1,Jp,A0,tau1,tau2] - AbsorbanceA1[#,t1,Jp,A0,tau1,tau2]
```

for each value in `PavP` by replacing `#` with that value. This results in a `List` which is accessed by `DeltaA1`.