# Assignments in ParallelDo when using indexed variables

Tags: parallelization, assignment

For convenience I use an indexed variables syntax to hold results of long computations for different integer parameters:

```
zeros[30] = longComputation[30]
zeros[40] = longComputation[40]
(* etc *)
```

I need to execute these computations for several values of the parameter. Since computations are completely independent, I thought that I could speed it up somewhat by evaluating these computations in parallel:

```
SetSharedVariable[zeros]

ParallelDo[
  zeros[n] = longComputation[n],
  {n, 30, 70, 10}
]
```

This does not work, however. I'm getting error messages like this one from each kernel:

```
Set::write: Tag Null in Null[30] is Protected.
```

and `zeros[n]` have weird values assigned to them:

```
In[171]:= zeros[30]
Out[171]= Null[30]
```

What's going on here and how to do what I want?

Comment: `longComputation(n)` is not correct Mathematica syntax for a function call.  In this case you would need `SetSharedFunction` as you are dealing with `DownValues`.  However, the communication overhead you introduce with this is likely going to negate any benefits or parallelization.  Try to write parallel code that never requires write access to the same variable from different threads.  Reformulate your problm in terms of ParallelMap or ParallelTable.

Comment: @Szabolcs If you were writing this as an answer I don't think my answer should prevent you from posting this as such. You make very good points about performance.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it incorrectly. Of course it should be `longComputation[n]` :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to replace `SetSharedVariable` with `SetSharedFunction`.

```
longComputation[n_] := n

SetSharedFunction[zeros]

ParallelDo[
 zeros[n] = longComputation[n],
 {n, 30, 70, 10}
 ]
```

Why? From the docs of `SetSharedVariable`:

> Shared variables without a value evaluate to Null.

This is what was happening to you, because `zeros[30] = ...` defines a function (also known as a "downvalue"), not a variable. You can read more about this [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues). Among those types of values mentioned in that post functions correspond to downvalues and variables correspond to ownvalues.

Answer (score 5):

In this case you would need `SetSharedFunction` as you are dealing with `DownValues`. However, the communication overhead you introduce with this is likely going to negate any benefits or parallelization. Try to write parallel code that never requires write access to the same variable from different threads. Reformulate your problem in terms of `ParallelMap` or `ParallelTable`.

For example, why not this?

```
ParallelMap[{#, longComputation[#]}&, {30, 70, 10}]
```

Comment: Are you sure there would be a noticeable communication overhead? There are only five values to be evaluated, and each computation is fairly long.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev It's up to you to find out.  If there isn't in this case, there might be any time you use `zeros` (after `SetSharedFunction`) in a different parallel computation.  In general it is a good idea to avoid modifying the same variable from different kernels in Mathematica.  If you need to assign to `zeros`, you can do it *after* you've returned a result from a parallel computation, and avoid ever setting `zeros` as shared.

Comment: This is a one-time computation so I think it would be fine. But anyway, thanks for the warning!

Comment: @VladimirMatveev If you like, treat it as `goto` .  When people ask about doing such things on this site, in the majority of cases it turns out to be a bad idea.  It doesn't mean that there's no room for `SetSharedFunction` and it's *always* a bad idea.