# Parallelize import of many files

Tags: import, parallelization, data, indexed-variable

I'm trying to speed up the import of a large number of files, using ParallelTable to store them in a indexed variable, eqDump. The files are in the folder "Frames" and are named "Conf_Run.1000", "Conf_Run.2000", ... Here is what I've tried,

```
    Clear[eqDump];    
    SetSharedFunction[eqDump];
    ParallelTable[
      eqDump[t] = Import["Frames/Conf_Run." <> ToString[t]
                    ,"Table"
                    ,HeaderLines -> 9]
    ,{t, 5000, 1000000, 5000}];
```

But the execution doesn't even seems to start, the kernels remain idle. I don't know whats happening, since I think it should work in the same way as [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80325/assignments-in-paralleldo-when-using-indexed-variables) for example. I've tried also to `SetSharedVariable[t]` since I supposed each kernel should know the current t value, but doesn't seem to help.

I'm using Mathematica 10.0.0 on Linux system with a 3-core (6-threads) CPU. Two 4GB memory modules that should be working in dual-channel. Only one HDD.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you working on a computer system with a parallel I/O capability ?  And I mean parallel all the way from RAM to the metal so multiple drives, multiple channels, ...

Comment: You may have to provide the full path name.Please also indicate with operating system and which Mathematica version you use.
BTW: My experience with `SetSharedFunction` is that there usually is a better (more efficient) way of doing what I want to do.
In your case I would not use `SetSharedFunction` at all, but try something like `res=ParallelTable[
    Inactive[Set][ eqDump[t] , Import[...`
And then on the result, in the main session, use `Activate[res]`

Comment: Thanks both for fast comment!
@HighPerformanceMark Actually didn't thought about that... maybe thats the thing.

Comment: @RolfMertig Updated question with system specifications. Will try what you suggest. I think there is no problem with the path since I previously issued a SetDirectory[] and got no errors when doing Table[]. Will try also justo to be sure.

Comment: "Only one HDD." So there is no hope to parallelize this. The HDD is by far the slowest resource and you have only one of them.

Comment: If you have only the one HDD it probably helps if you have only one process reading data at a time, and doing so in as large chunks as your RAM and your computation can cope with.  Same for writing.  The situation might be different with SSDs, but on consumer-grade hardware they seem often to have the same controllers as used for HDDs which makes them no more useful for parallel I/O.

Comment: The other situation where you might benefit from 'parallelisation' on a computer with only one HDD is where computation time for each file read is significant.  You might then see some benefit if Process 1 reads its file, then goes off for a while to think about it, leaving Process 2 to play with the disk, ..., and so on.  But this requires careful orchestration.