# What makes items with head `Function` different?

Tags: evaluation, syntax, pure-function

I apologize beforehand for the muddleheadedness of this question.  It reflects the fact that I'm trying to interpret outward "behaviors" of *Mathematica* expressions without having any understanding of the scheme underlying these behaviors.

---

Among symbols that are "defined" (whatever this means), those that have head `Function` seem to be fundamentally different from most others in that they "respond" to a trailing square-bracket-delimited subexpression:

```
{Function[{}, 5], Function[{}, 5][]}
```

> ```
> {Function[{}, 5], 5}
> ```

```
{3, 3[]}
```

> ```
> {3, 3[]}
> ```

(I'm using the verb "respond" as the opposite of what happens when *Mathematica*'s evaluation, as in the case of `3[]`, produces no visible change at all, not even a warning or error message.)

What is the difference in the ways that *Mathematica* evaluates `Function[{}, 5][]` and `3[]` that accounts for the fact that the former returns something different from itself, but not the latter?

Is there a way to display a breakdown *Mathematica*'s evaluation that clearly shows the basis of this difference?

One other head I know of that marks items that "respond" to a trailing `[...]` is `Association` (the "response" is either the value associated with the "key" in the `[...]`, if such exists, or an item with head `Missing`).  Are there any others?

---

Unfortunately, this question is muddled by this sort of thing:

```
ClearAll[foo];

{foo, foo[5]}

foo[5] = 4; {foo, foo[5]}

{foo, foo[7]}

Head[foo]
```

> ```
> {foo, foo[5]}
>
> {foo, 4}
>
> {foo, foo[7]}
>
> Symbol
> ```

IOW, *under some circumstances*, an item with head `Symbol` will "respond" to *some* trailing `[...]` expressions.  Hmph...

Comment: In your place, I'd read Chapter 7 on evaluation process in David Wagner's book "Power programming in Mathematica" - available for free here on the site for download - this should clarify a lot of issues. The `Function` construct is special, and has a special evaluation semantics, which is why you see the difference. Also, read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96).

Comment: You should also realize, that, say, `Function[{}, 5][]` is equivalent to `5&[]`, *not* `5[]`. I don't claim very deep knowledge, but one of the lessons to learn from Leonid's link, is that a function is a bit different from a replacement rule that's created when you give a symbol a DownValue. I hope, however, that if I'm grossly inaccurate, the more knowledgeable folks will correct me here.