# Argument pattern behavior for built-in symbol

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, argument-patterns

I'm having troubles with this:

```
test1[forAll[t,x_]]:=x
test2[ForAll[t,x_]]:=x
```

While syntactically exact, `test1` works and `test2` does not:

```
?test1
(* test1[forAll[t,x_]]:=x *)

?test2
(* test2[x_]:=x *)
```

Why doesn't `?test2` output `test2[ForAll[t,x_]]:=x`?

**Edit 2**

For anyone interested - for yet unknown reasons - this and only this **works as expected**:

```
test3[ForAll[t,t_]]:=t
```

**Edit 3**

The legit working solution to non-standard evaluation traps like this is to use unambiguous pattern matching syntax that does not provide any hints to the system that this can be evaluated:

```
test2[(f:ForAll)[t,x_]]:=x
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You need `HoldFirst` or similar attribute, otherwise it is  the same as defining `f[1+1]:=whatever`.

Comment: @Kuba, I do not want `HoldFirst` for this method. I *need* it without `HoldFirst`

Comment: @Kuba, btw I just tested `test3[a_+b_]:=a` and it actually **does** work: `?test3 (* => test3[a_+b_]:=a *)`

Comment: Because `a_+b_` does not evaluate further while `ForAll[t,x_]` does, to `x_`.

Comment: closely related: [19897](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19897/5478)

Comment: @Kuba, well, `test2[ForAll[t_,x_]]:=x` does not work either then. Should not evaluate. But I see that `ForAll[x_,y_]` still evaluates regardless. Thanks. This must be some kind of bug.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is a bug. `ForAll` has no `Options` (specifically `HoldFirst`), and I think by default, it takes the symbol that's in the first argument and looks for it in the second argument. Compare `ForAll[x_, x_^2]` with `ForAll[x_, y_^2]`. The second evaluates to `y_^2` because it has no `x_` in it.

Comment: @march, evaluating with implicit assumption that two variables have different values is a bug.

Comment: I mean, I don't agree with you: I'd say it's a design choice (and, giving the programmers the benefit of the doubt, there's probably a good reason for it!). In any case, you can always make your own `forAll` that doesn't evaluate until the variable in the first argument appears in the expression in the second argument, and then it calls `ForAll`.

Comment: @march, the problem is that I'm quite familiar with a few other pattern matching languages and none of them exhibit such a behavior. That's actually a quite fundamental assumption in all of them - that `(symb ?a ?b)` also means `(symb ?a ?a)` if not explicitly stated the opposite

Comment: I see. Well, you'll need more of an expert than me, then.

Comment: to complete the mess, I've found that `ForAll[t,t_]` does work as expected and added it as an edit to OP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, though `SetDelayed` (`:=`) has `HoldAll` attribute, it still evaluates its 1st argument in this case, this behavior has been discussed in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95557/1871). To be specific, when `test2` is defined, the argument `ForAll[t, x_]` will be evaluated.

Now the question becomes

> Why `ForAll[t, x_]` evaluates to `x_`?

and this has been explained in the **Scope** of the document of `ForAll`:

> If the expression does not explicitly contain a variable, `ForAll`
>   simplifies automatically:
>
> ```
> ForAll[x, y == 0] 
> (* y == 0 *)
> ```

In your case, `x_` doesn't explicitly contain `t`, and it's automatically simplified, while `t_` explicitly contain `t` so it's not. (Notice the `FullForm` of `t_` is `Pattern[t, Blank[]]` i.e. a function with 2 arguments whose 1st agrument is an explicit `t`. )

To get the desired function definition, you can make use of `Unevaluated`:

```
ClearAll@test2    
test2[Unevaluated@ForAll[t, x_]] := x
DownValues@test2
(* {HoldPattern[test2[ForAll[t, x_]]] :> x} *)

test2[ForAll[t, t + t^2]]
(* t + t^2 *)
```

But notice this function still won't work as expected if the `ForAll[…]` evaluates to something else, for example:

```
test2[ForAll[t, x]]
(* test2[x] *)
```

If you want it to evaluate to `x`, then `Unevaluated` again or as mentioned in the comment above, use `HoldFirst`:

```
test2[Unevaluated@ForAll[t, x]]
(* x *)
SetAttributes[test2, HoldFirst]
test2[ForAll[t, x]]
(* x *)
```

Comment: xzczd, thank you for detailed answer. Could you please elaborate on how does `t_` explicitly contain `t`? I thought `t_` is just a local pattern variable and does not explicitly state anything and could mean *any* expression when matched regardless of its name?

Comment: Check my edit. If you're still confused, feel free to ask.

Comment: many thanks! that makes a lot of sense and completes my understanding of how pattern matching is implemented on top of symbolic rules engine in MMA. Btw, the word "function" may add confusion and I am not sure if this is even correct for symbol `Pattern` (I doubt if it emits a `Function` in any scenario)

Comment: I think it's OK to use the word "function" to name a non-atomic expression, even if it doesn't evaluate to anything else. In mathematics we'll simply call $f(x,y)$ a function even if we know nothing about the specific function relationship represented by $f$, right?