# Can a symbol have both OwnValues and DownValues?

Tags: core-language

Mathematica Version 11.2 desktop / Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

I am trying to understand if a symbol can have both OwnValues and DownValues.

Is this acceptable or not acceptable?

As an experiment, I noticed that when one assigns the OwnValues such as "y = a" compared to the DownValues makes a difference which I cannot explain. The following is an example.

```
y[] = b; y[x] = 1; y = a;
??y
```

> Global`y
>   $\qquad$y = a $\quad$ y[ ] = b $\quad$ y[x] = 1

```
{OwnValues[y], DownValues[y]}
(* {{HoldPattern[y]:>a},{HoldPattern[y[]]:>b,HoldPattern[y[x]]:>1}} *)

Remove[y]

y=a; y[]=b; y[x]=1;
??y
```

> Global`y
>   $\qquad$ y = a

```
{OwnValues[y], DownValues[y]}
(* {{HoldPattern[y]:>a}, {}} *)
```

The help says `Set` ( = ) has attribute `HoldFirst`. Therefore, the lhs should not be evaluated. So it should not matter if you have `y`, `y[]`, or `y[x]` because they are not evaluated. However, for `y = a; y[] = b; y[x] = 1;`, it does seem to matter since only `y = a` is defined.

Please clarify.

Comment: Regarding `HoldFirst`, I immediately thought of Leonid's 2015 [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95557/why-is-the-first-argument-of-the-setdelayed-evaluated#comment258631_95557):  "[Having a hold attribute] simply means that arguments are passed to the function in unevaluated form, but does not restrict what functions decide to do with them."

Comment: See the second bullet point in the first chapter in [tutorial/Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html) to learn why this will be a problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, a symbol can have both own-values and down-values, but it is usually bad practice to give a symbol both. Further, the order in which they are created matters, but there are problems both ways.

#### OwnValue first

```
y = 42;
OwnValues @ y
```

> `{HoldPattern[y] :> 42}`

But now you can't set a own-value, because

```
y[42] = 0
```

> Set::write: Tag Integer in 42[42] is Protected.
> `0`

```
DownValues @ y
```

> `{}`

#### DowValue first

```
x[42] = 0;
DownValues @ x
```

> `{HoldPattern[x[42]] :> 0}`

```
x = 42;
OwnValues @ x
```

> `{HoldPattern[x] :> 42}`

The symbol `x` has both an own-value and a down-value, but look what happens when `x[42]` is evaluated.

x[42]

> `42[42]`

This happens because under normal evaluation rules, Mathematica evaluates the head `x` of `x[42]` before anything else. When evaluating a symbol such as `x`, it looks at own-vales first and finds one. It uses that own-value to replace `x` with 42. It next evaluates the parts (arguments) of expression and of course gets 42, and so `x[42]` evaluates to `42[42]`. Mathematica doesn't look for a down-value of `x` because it doesn't need to.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating this. This essentially means to me that it is completely unpractical to assign OwnValues and DownValues to the same symbol, right?

Comment: @TheoTiger. Yes