# Making an animation of the motion of a particle

Tags: physics, homework, interactive

I am new here. I just installed Mathematica and am learning the basics. I need to solve three equations of the motion of a particle using `Do`, `ListPlot`, and `Animate`. Kindly help me to solve me one, then I will do the other two by myself.

```
vf = vi + a t
s =  vi t + (1/2)a t^2
2as = vf^2 + vi^2
```

This is what I have tried for first equation.

```
vi = 0;
vf = 22;
a = 10;
t = 60;
steps = 50;
vi[0] = 0.8;
vf[0] = 1.3;
a[0] = 0.7;
t[0] = 0.0;
Do[vf[n] = vi[n] + a[n]*t[n], {n, 0, steps}]
data = Table[vf[n], {n, 0, steps}];
ListPlot[data]

r = 0.5;
Animate[
  Show[Graphics[Disk[{vf[n]}, r], Axes -> True]], 
  {n, 0, steps, 30}]
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve for? You have `vi, vf, a, t`, and `vi[0], vf[0], a[0]  t[0]` conflicting.  You can't do that.  You can solve for `at` from the first equation with `vi` and `vf`, which is different ? from `vi[0]` and `vf[0]`.  I don't know what `vit` is, but if you know it, you can solve for `s` in the second equation, and then solve for `a` in the last equation.

Comment: @bill watts i am liitle confuse if you give me some hint to do it

Comment: Can't do it with the data you have. `vf` does not equal `vi + a t`.  Since you assign each variable in that equation, there is nothing to solve for.  also 2as should be 2 a s.  Multiplication is either `*` or space.  Since `s` is not assigned, that is the only thing you can solve for, and that only requires your second equation.   Everything else is overly and inconsistently specified.

Answer (score 1):

#### Math problem

```
vf = vi + a t /. {vi -> 0, a -> 10, t -> 60}
```

> `600`

This is inconsistent with `vf == 22`

#### Mathematica problem

Making assignments to a simple variable and and an indexed variable of the same name (such as `t = 60` and `t[0] = 0.0`) is asking for trouble. This is explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160742/3066), but may be too advanced for a beginner, so just accept that you shouldn't do it.

#### Kinematics problem

For simple kinematics problems like yours, I believe it is better to express the motion as a function rather than as an expression. So

```
v[t_] := v0 + a t
s[t_] := s0 + v0  t + a/2 t^2
```

#### My problem

I have no idea what you are trying to express with the reation

```
2 as = vf^2 + vi^2
```

#### Demonstrating the motion

Now let's see what I can do about making a demonstration of the kinematics. I choose to use `Manipulate` and `Plot` rather than `Animate` and `ListPlot`. Note that `Manipulate` supports animation. To run an animation, just click on the "+" on the right of the slider. I prefer `Plot` over `ListPlot` because motion is essentially continuous rather than discrete.

The velocity versus time plot

```
With[{tmax = 60},
  Manipulate[
    Block[{a = 10., v0 = 0.},
      Plot[v[t], {t, 0, tt}, PlotRange -> {{0, tmax}, {v0, v[tmax]}}]],
    {{tt, 1, "t"}, 1, tmax, 1, AppearanceElements -> All}]]
```

[image: velocity]

The distance versus time plot

```
With[{tmax = 60},
  Manipulate[
    Block[{a = 10., v0 = 0., s0 = 0.},
      Plot[s[t], {t, 0, tt}, PlotRange -> {{0, tmax}, {s0, s[tmax]}}]],
    {{tt, 1, "t"}, 1, tmax, 1, AppearanceElements -> All}]]
```

[image: distance]

If you insist on using Animate and ListPlot, you might do something like

```
With[{tmax = 20},
  DynamicModule[{vData, sData},
    Animate[
      Block[{a = 10., v0 = 0., s0 = 0.},
        vData = Table[{t, v[t]}, {t, 0, tt}];
        sData = Table[{t, s[t]}, {t, 0, tt}];
        ListPlot[{vData, sData},
          PlotRange -> {{0, tmax}, {0., s[tmax]}},
          PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]],
    {{tt, 0, "t"}, 0, tmax, 1}]]]
```

[image: animation]

but, in my opinion, it does not elucidate the kinematics a well as the two Manipulate expressions.

Comment: thanks for the help but i tell you seriously i did't understand a single thing. will you do for the first equation of the motion.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code and the Mathematica syntax. You have to describe your kinematics equations into finite elements. For a constant acceleration, each steps are $\delta t$ apart. You will notice I have used `Print` to get results out of the `With` (If not, only the last expression is printed out, the `Animate`). Try this:

```
With[{
vi = 0,
  \[Delta]t = 0.1,
  a = 10,
  steps = 50,
  r = 0.5},
  Do[vf[n] = vi + a*n*\[Delta]t, {n, 0, steps}];
 data = Table[vf[n], {n, 0, steps}]; 
 Print[ListPlot[data]];
 Animate[Show[Graphics[Disk[{n, vf[n]}, r], PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 50}}, 
Axes -> True]], {n, 0, steps, 1}]]
```