# Can a Symbol have more than one OwnValue?

Tags: core-language

The `DownValues`, `UpValues`, and `OwnValues` functions are all plural. In general, a Symbol may have multiple DownValues or UpValues. For example:

```
f[x_]:= x^2
f[x_, y_]:= x^2 + y^2
DownValues[f]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[x_]]:>x^2,HoldPattern[f[x_,y_]]:>x^2+y^2}
> ```

Can a Symbol have more than one OwnValue?

Comment: If a symbol had more than one OwnValue, what would you expect to see as the result of evaluating it?

Comment: Oh, I have no idea. But Mathematica has no problem with [assigning an OwnValue that makes a DownValue inaccessible](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160740/can-a-symbol-have-both-ownvalues-and-downvalues), so I see no reason it would have a problem with an inaccessible OwnValue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is yes, as Henrik Schumacher's answer pointed out. Leonid Shifrin gave a more natural way to get multiple `OwnValues` in the comments to Henrik's answer. However, the situation is more complicated and appears to expose some undefined/inconsistent behavior.

### Unconditional Assignments

As Henrik's answer explains, one can write to `OwnValues[x]`:

```
ClearAll[x];
OwnValues[x] = {x -> 1, x :> 2};
OwnValues[x]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[x] :> 1, HoldPattern[x] :> 2}
> ```

Whether or not an `OwnValue` is a `Set` or `SetDelayed` is not reported by `OwnValues[x]` but is reported by `Definition[x]`:

```
Definition[x]
```

> ```
> x = 1 
>
> x := 2
> ```

The ordering of `OwnValues[x]` matters. The first rule (actually, the first rule *that matches*, see below) determines what `x` evaluates to.

Setting `OwnValues[x]` directly should be avoided, as it can lead to inconsistent behavior (see last section) and can circumvent Mathematica's behavior of placing more specific rules before more general rules as described in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html):

> If a new rule that you give is determined to be more specific than existing rules, it is, however, placed before them. When the rules are used, they are tested in order.

### Conditional Assignments

Leonid Shifrin provides another way to obtain multiple `OwnValues`, namely conditional assignment. The placement of the condition determines whether the rule is prepended or appended:

```
ClearAll[x];
(* Appends the rules to OwnValues[x]. *)
x /; TrueQ[y] := 1;
x /; !TrueQ[y] := 2;

(* Prepends the rules to OwnValues[x]. *)
x := 4 /; EvenQ[y];
x := 1 /; OddQ[y];
OwnValues[x]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[x] :> 4 /; EvenQ[y], HoldPattern[x] :> 1 /; OddQ[y], 
>  HoldPattern[x /; TrueQ[y]] :> 1, HoldPattern[x /; ! TrueQ[y]] :> 2}
> ```

The first rule that matches is what `x` evaluates to. (Note that this example uses `SetDelayed`.)

### `Set` versus `SetDelayed`

#### With existing `OwnValues`

The behavior of `Set` is different from `SetDelayed`. Multiple `OwnValues` of the form `x /; TrueQ[y] = 1;` (condition on the *lhs*) can coexist with each other and with any form of `SetDelayed`:

```
ClearAll[x];
x /; TrueQ[y] = 1;
x /; ! TrueQ[y] = 2;
x := 3;
OwnValues[x]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[x] :> 3, HoldPattern[x /; TrueQ[y]] :> 1, 
> HoldPattern[x /; ! TrueQ[y]] :> 2}
> ```

However, a call of the form `x = 1` or `x = 2 /; EvenQ[y]` (condition on the *rhs*) will *always* clear any existing members of `OwnValues[x]`, no matter its contents:

```
ClearAll[x];
x /; TrueQ[y] := 1;
OwnValues[x]

x = 2 /; EvenQ[y];
OwnValues[x]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[x /; TrueQ[y]] :> 1}
>
> {HoldPattern[x] :> 2 /; EvenQ[y]}
> ```

This is not true of (unconditional) `SetDelayed` which only replaces the *first* rule of the form `x:>1` or `x->1` in `OwnValues[x]`, if such a rule exists:

```
ClearAll[x];
OwnValues[x] = {x -> 1, x -> 2}; (* However, see last section. *)
x /; TrueQ[y] := 3;
OwnValues[x]

x := 4;
OwnValues[x]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[x] :> 1, HoldPattern[x] :> 2, 
> HoldPattern[x /; TrueQ[y]] :> 3}
>
> {HoldPattern[x] :> 4, HoldPattern[x] :> 2, 
> HoldPattern[x /; TrueQ[y]] :> 3}
> ```

#### With subsequent conditional assignments

A similar pattern holds for *subsequent* conditional assignments (although see last section). First with `Set`:

```
ClearAll[x];
x = 1;
OwnValues[x]

x /; TrueQ[y] := 2;
OwnValues[x]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[x] :> 1}
>
> {HoldPattern[x /; TrueQ[y]] :> 2}
> ```

Now with `SetDelayed`:

```
ClearAll[x];
x := 1;
OwnValues[x]

x /; TrueQ[y] := 2;
OwnValues[x]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[x] :> 1}
>
> {HoldPattern[x] :> 1, HoldPattern[x /; TrueQ[y]] :> 2}
> ```

### Inconsistent/Undefined Behavior

It matters *how* a `Set` rule is placed into `OwnValues[x]`: whether by writing directly to `OwnValues`, `OwnValues[x] = {x->1}`, or "indirectly", `x = 1`.

```
ClearAll[x];
OwnValues[x] = {x -> 1};
x /; TrueQ[y] := 2;
OwnValues[x]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[x] :> 1, HoldPattern[x /; TrueQ[y]] :> 2}
> ```

Compare to

```
ClearAll[x];
x = 1;
x /; TrueQ[y] := 2;
OwnValues[x]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[x /; TrueQ[y]] :> 2}
> ```

(As previously stated, an unconditional `SetDelayed` will overwrite the first `x->1` rule.)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it can, but only the first *matching* rule gets applied:

```
ClearAll[x];
OwnValues[x] = {x :> 1, x :> 2};
OwnValues[x]
Definition[x]
x
```

> {HoldPattern[x] :> 1, HoldPattern[x] :> 2}
>
> x : = 1
>
> x : = 2
>
> 1

Compare also to

```
ClearAll[x];
OwnValues[x] = {x -> 1, x -> 2};
OwnValues[x]
Definition[x]
x
```

> {HoldPattern[x] :> 1, HoldPattern[x] :> 2}
>
> x = 1
>
> x = 2
>
> 1

In a comment, Leonid brought up conditional rules in order to point out that it is really the first *matching* rule that applies. Here is an example that shows that you can do "interesting" things with it:

```
ClearAll[x];
b = False;
OwnValues[x] = {x :> (b = False; 1) /; b, x :> (b = True; -1) /; ! b};
```

This way, the "value" of `x` after evaluation depends on the state of the boolean `b`. As the `OwnValues` of `x` contain rules with side effects that change the state of `b`, this implies that the "value" of `x` changes every time it is evaluated.

```
Table[x, {10}]
```

> {-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1}

Comment: One can define conditional `OwnValues`, where rules other than the first may apply. For example, `x /; TrueQ[y] := 1;x /; ! TrueQ[y] := 2;`. By default, the second rule applies. If you set `y` to `True`, the first rule will apply. So, your answer is not fully correct as written.

Comment: @Leonid That's worthy of an answer, is it not? :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't think so :) If it gets incorporated into Henrik's answer in some form, I will be happy.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Very good point. I tried to integrate it to my post. Are you okay with it?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Sure. Since the first matching rule is also the strategy for other `...Values`, the `OwnValues` is not that different from them in this respect. The difference is really that it is much harder to find an uncontrived example of multiple `OwnValues` for the same symbol, because that would mostly mean using a symbol like a function that would depend on global variables.

Comment: I have discovered that the situation is more complicated—and won't fit in a comment. Is it acceptable protocol to add another answer?

Comment: @RobertJacobson Of course it is.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin @Mr.Wizard @Henrik Thanks, all. I made a new answer that incorporates how Mathematica orders `OwnValues`, differences between `Set` and `SetDelayed` and where the condition is (lhs or rhs), and some inconsistent behavior when assigning `OwnValues` directly.