# What makes a pattern more general?

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, upvalues, downvalues

This is a rewording of the question. The original post is below.

**How come that a pattern for an expression with a specific head is not more specific than a pattern for an expression with a generic head?**

The code below provides the example. The original wording of the question includes references to "evaluation procedure" in an effort to make the case that the order in which Mathematica tried the patterns is not what I expected.

---

According to [The Ordering of Definitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheOrderingOfDefinitions.html):

> [Mathematica] follows the principle of trying to put more general
>   definitions after more specific ones.

Also, from [The Standard Evaluation Procedure](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStandardEvaluationProcedure.html)

> In the standard evaluation procedure, [Mathematica] first
>   evaluates the head of an expression and then evaluates each element of
>   the expression …

With that in mind, consider the following code:

```
Clear[h];
h /: _[___, _h, ___] := "Pattern 2";
h /: f[_h, ___] := "Pattern 1";
f[h[1]]
(*"Pattern 2"*)
```

In my understanding of the two quotes above, the output should be "Pattern 1". My reasoning is that when patterns are evaluated, their heads are evaluated first and `f` is less general than `_`.

From [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7904/8803), I gather that those two patterns are incomparable:

```
Internal`ComparePatterns[_[___, _h, ___], f[_h, ___]]
(*Incomparable*)
```

That explains the "Pattern 2" outcome. I need help to catch the error in my reasoning though.

---

*Update to address a comment.*

The answers in [a previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8619/8803) suggest

> [the algorithm used internally for pattern ordering] might forever remain an implementation secret, like the 'canonical order'.

Even if that is true, that secret implementation should conform to the published documents. Hence my question is whether there are any flaws in my reasoning. For example, it might be possible that pattern evaluation does not follow The Standard Evaluation Procedure. If so, is there some documentation about it? If there is no error in my previous statement

> when patterns are evaluated, their heads are evaluated first and f is less general than _

does the code above show a bug?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8619/5478 is this a duplicate?

Comment: I think the attribututions of the quotes to "The Ordering of Definitions" and "The Standard Evaluation Procedure" should be reversed.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Nice catch … fixed it

Comment: There isn't a concept of "evaluation of patterns" in Mathematica. The key point is that earlier patterns are tried before later ones. And since you defined `_[___, _h, ___]` first, that's the one it matches to.  The blurb about `Heads` being evaluated first just means that `f` evaluates first in your example before all else.  Look: try adding the definition `f = HoldComplete` in your example, and you'll see `f` gets swapped out for `HoldComplete` before anything; and that stops your `UpValues` on `h` from working.

Comment: @QuantumDot there’s definition reordering, though, that can mess that up. Mathematica does attempt to order the definitions, although it is true that a definition that conflicts with a previous one won’t be added.

Comment: The result of ``Internal`ComparePatterns[HoldPattern@_[___, _h, ___], HoldPattern@_[_h, ___]]`` suggests that it is not the heads, `_` vs. `f`, but the arguments that cause the comparator to return `"Incomparable"`. The result of `ClearAll[h, f]; h /: _[_h] := "1"; h /: f[_h] := "2"; f[h[1]]` also supports this. The question is why does the internal algorithm fail to decide which is more specific, in either the OP's example or this simpler one with just a difference in arguments? I don't think the internal details are known. The docs do warn it fails sometimes, though it's easy to decide here.

Comment: @MichaelE2 `ComparePatterns` does not seem a reliable predictor of pattern ordering. Try `h /: _[_h] := 1; h /: f[_h] := 2; UpValues[h]`. The order in the list of up values is different than the order those patterns were entered. That is, Mathematica did order them yet `ComparePatterns` says they are incomparable. By the way, I am assuming that the order returned by `UpValues` is the order in which patterns are tried.

Comment: @Hector ``Internal`ComparePatterns[HoldPattern@f[_h], HoldPattern@_[_h]]`` says the first is more specific.  Note that ``GeneralUtilities`PatternOrder``, whose code you can inspect, uses ``Internal`ComparePatterns`` on patterns in both orders to determine the pattern order.  Not sure why that's the way ``Internal`ComparePatterns`` works.  I don't recall seeing on this site or anywhere else an official confirmation that this is how pattern-order is determined for function definitions.

Answer (score 7):

## The example at hand

One part of the confusion seems to arise from the fact that the patterns that are compared differ in two aspects: The additional `___` and the head (`f` vs `_`). Let us first consider two separate examples, where the definitions only differ in one aspect.

### Additional `___`

We see the same behavior (i.e. patterns are incomparable) for the following simpler function definition (no upvalues and a fixed head):

```
Clear@f
f[___, 1, ___] := 1
f[1, ___] := 2
f[1]
(* 1 *)

Clear@f
f[1, ___] := 2
f[___, 1, ___] := 1
f[1]
(* 2 *)
```

This demonstrates (without having to rely on any undocumented function) that MMA deems the patterns incomparable. I have no idea why this particular example behaves the way it does, as it seems rather trivial to decide which one is more general…

### Head `f` vs `_`

To show that the issue has nothing to do with `f` vs `_`, consider the following example:

```
Clear@h
h /: f[_h, ___] := 1
h /: _[_h, ___] := 2
f[h[1]]
(* 1 *)

Clear@h
h /: _[_h, ___] := 2
h /: f[_h, ___] := 1
f[h[1]]
(* 1 *)
```

As can be seen, the pattern with head `f` is correctly identified as more specific.

So the question "why a pattern with `f` as the head is not more specific than a pattern with any head" is based on a false premise.

## "The ordering of patterns" vs. "The standard evaluation procedure"

Second, I think you're confusing the ordering of definitions with the evaluation procedure: When you define a new rule for a function, the rule is inserted into the down/up-values of the associated symbol according to it's specificity. This is what the linked question is all about - i.e. how MMA decides where to insert a given rule. This has nothing to do with the second statement, "heads are evaluated first". This only affects how an expression is evaluated, given the rules that are already present at this point. Consider the following example:

```
h = Hold
h[Print@1]
(* Hold[Print[1]] *)
```

As you can see, the head of the expression, `h` is first evaluated to `Hold`, before the `Print@1` expression is evaluated.

So, to summarize:

- When a new rule for a symbol is defined, the left and right side of the assignment are first evaluated as appropriate (in most cases this means not at all). The rule is then inserted according to its specificity.
- When an expression is evaluated, the head is evaluated first, before any of the arguments. For `h[a][b]`, this means `h`, then `a`, then `h[a]`, then `b`, then `h[a][b]`.

Comment: Yes, I did mix "ordering of patterns" with "standard evaluation procedure" … I realize now that although patterns are evaluated (hence the need for HoldPattern when you do not want them evaluated), their evaluation is not what determines the order in which they are used. Thank you, that mistake will not happen again. However, the question is really about why a pattern with `f` as the head is not more specific than a pattern with any head.

Comment: I've updated the answer to address your comment more directly - I hope this shows that the head has nothing to do with the issue. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer as to why adding `___` doesn't make the pattern less specific, but incomparable instead.

Answer (score 7):

From [this very nice answer by Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127/4999):

> The common statement you can encounter is that "UpValues are applied before DownValues". This must be clarified: for `f[g[args]]` it means that UpValues for `g` are applied before DownValues for `f`, provided that the evaluation process already went all they way "down" to innermost parts, and then went back "up".

In the OP's example, the upvalues for `h` are applied before any downvalues of `f` (of which none are given).

The other factor, which OP has already figured out, is that because the patterns are incomparable, they are applied in the order made.  Reverse the definitions and you get `"Pattern 1"`:

```
ClearAll[hh];
hh /: ff[_hh, ___] := "Pattern 1";
hh /: _[___, _hh, ___] := "Pattern 2";
ff[hh[1]]
(*  "Pattern 1"  *)
```

The ordering of the upvalues can been seen by using [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html):

```
UpValues[hh]
(*
  {HoldPattern[ff[_hh, ___]] :> "Pattern 1", 
   HoldPattern[_[___, _hh, ___]] :> "Pattern 2"}
*)
```

Finally, somewhat of an aside.  The OP quotes a part of "The Standard Evaluation Procedure" about evaluating the head first.  This means in `f[h[1]]` that `f` itself is evaluated.  But the upvalues for `h` will still be applied before the downvalues for `f`.  Evaluating the head first makes a difference when the head itself evaluates to a different expression.  The effect of this rule can be seen in the following:

```
g = f;
g[x___] := Length@{x};
g[h[1]]
(*  "Pattern 2"  *)
```

If you use [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html), you can see the steps `{{g, f}, f[h[1]], "Pattern 2"}`; but `Trace` does not tell you which rule is applied.

Note the definition `g[x___]` defined a downvalue for `f`, not for `g` (see [Why is the first argument of the SetDelayed evaluated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95557/why-is-the-first-argument-of-the-setdelayed-evaluated) and the SO Q&A 
[Unwanted evaluation in assignments in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7408310)):

```
DownValues[f]
DownValues[g]
(*
  {HoldPattern[f[x___]] :> Length[{x}]}
  {}
*)

OwnValues[g]
(*  {HoldPattern[g] :> f}  *)
```