# How does Wolfram Language implement for enabling symbols to receive various forms of parameters?

Tags: implementation-details, built-in-symbols

How does the official implement a list/tuple of parameters that can be different in type and quantity as a whole?

After re-read @Szabolcs['s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/202912#comment524339_202912) and @MichaelE2['s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/202912#comment524383_202912) comments.
Finally, I accepted the suggestion in @Kuba's [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/202912#comment524348_202912) ("`tutorial/evaluation`") as the "answer" according to @Shredderroy's [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/202912#comment524363_202912):

> the `tutorial/evaluation` suggestion by @Kuba is the best explanation that the general public can provide since Mathematica is a proprietary system.

---

#### Details of the original question:

In particular, [`RegularPolygon`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularPolygon) and [`Plot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D) – these two symbols make me most curious:

The lists of parameters accepted by `RegularPolygon` can be any of the following (can be found at the beginning of the official document):

```
RegularPolygon[{r, θ}, n]
RegularPolygon[{x, y}, rspec, n]
```

The lists of parameters of `Plot3D` can be any of the following:

```
Plot3D[{…, w[f_i], …}, …]
Plot3D[…, {x, y}∈reg]
```

Although using any programming language can achieve automatic matching of parameters by defining properties/rules/traits or by pattern matching, I still want to know what the **specific implementation** of these are by the **official**.

I am very grateful to you!

Comment: The question is not completely clear to me. Can you explain in more details, with more examples? Also, be sure to include everything in the question body (never rely on the title).

Comment: Please read up on pattern matching and defining functions. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndProgramsOverview.html

Comment: @Szabolcs Not like that (I read them two years ago), I am not asking "definition functions" (especially user-defined), but how "the diversity of parameter lists" is implemented inside Wolfram Language.

Comment: Is this what you mean? `foo[x_Integer]:=1; foo[x_String]:=2]`

Comment: @Kuba No. Please see my comment right above yours.

Comment: @ooo isn't my example of 'parameter lists' diverse enough? How about `foo[x_Integer, y_Region]:=1; foo[x_String]:=2]`? It may be that I am missing the point ofc.

Comment: @Kuba I'm not care about: you (as a user) write the code of the function's definition, but confusing on: when passing arguments to the **built-in symbols**, **how** does the **kernel (language itself)** process??

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how to achieve this in other programming language?

Comment: Performing 'evaluation', see `tutorial/Evaluation`.

Comment: The long comment thread illustrates well why this was not a clearly written question (BTW the title is still not decoupled)...

Comment: Interesting. The question was clear to me the moment I read the title. I think the `tutorial/evaluation` suggestion by @Kuba is the best explanation that the general public can provide since Mathematica is a proprietary system. Based on the description provided in the documentation there, it would not be too hard to suggest reasonable algorithms for implementing the ideas. But as to an authoritative account of the actual algorithms used by the Wolfram engineering team, well, that will probably be hard to come by.

Comment: Many WL functions are written at top level; i.e. in WL using definitions just like the user would. This is why changing system variables can be dangerous.

Comment: Related: [(96)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96), [(8619)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8619), [(178285)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/178285)

Comment: @Kuba After I read all the comments again, your last comment is the "answer" - thank you very much! And I realized that [duplicate] does exist, but the question that now reference to is not really corresponding (I had misconceived and mischosen it).