# Is this behaviour of pattern ordering of OptionsPattern stable and documented?

Tags: pattern-matching, downvalues

My version is `13.2`. This behaviour of `OptionsPattern` together with `` is extracted from some complicated functions.

### Motivation

```
f//Options={"a"->1};
f[x_]:={x,1}
f[x_,OptionsPattern[]]:={x,OptionValue["a"]}
```

```
f[1]//Trace
(*{f[1],{1,1}}*)
f[1,"a"->1]//Trace
(*{{a->1,a->1},f[1,a->1],{1,OptionValue[f,{a->1},a]},{OptionValue[f,{a->1},a],1},{1,1}}*)
```

The definition `f[x_]` seems redundant as a special case of `f[x_,OptionsPattern[]]`. But from the evaluation process we know that it makes `f[1]` more faster since the pattern matcher will match `f[x_]` firstly. Hence in the situation when the options are seldomly called, I add this redundant definition.

### Example

Considering the following two functions, it turns out Mathematica cannot render which pattern is more specific than the other.

```
f1//Options={"a"->1};
f1[x:_Symbol[___]...,y_String:"x"]:=
    {x,y};
f1[x:_Symbol[___]...,y_String:"x",OptionsPattern[]]:=
    {x,y,OptionValue["a"]};
    
f2//Options={"a"->1};
f2[x:_Symbol[___]...,y_String:"x",OptionsPattern[]]:=
    {x,y,OptionValue["a"]};
f2[x:_Symbol[___]...,y_String:"x"]:=
    {x,y};
```

[image]

- The `Optional` `y_String:"x"` is necessary to effect the order;
- The order of `Optional` and `OptionsPattern` does not matter.

These orderings will cause different behaviours, e.g.

```
f1[g[a,b]]//Trace
f1[g[a,b],"a"->0]//Trace
```

[image]

```
f2[g[a,b]]//Trace
f2[g[a,b],"a"->0]//Trace
```

[image]

For `f1`, the input `"a"->0` is matched with `_Symbol[___]` firstly, while for `f2`, it is matched with the `OptionsPattern[]`, leading to the different results.

In these examples, the second definitions are always shadowed by the first one.

### Question

- Is this behaviour of ordering of `DownValues` stable and documented?
- Is there a method of preventing the pattern matcher from matching `"a"->0` as `_Symbol[___]`?

---

### Edit

As suggested by @MichaelE2, the order can be checked by `Internal`ComparePatterns` and agrees with the practice.

```
GeneralUtilities`PatternOrder[{_Symbol[___]...,OptionsPattern[]},{_Symbol[___]...}]
(*1*)
```

```
GeneralUtilities`PatternOrder[{_Symbol[___]...,OptionsPattern[],_String:"x"},{_Symbol[___]...,_String:"x"}]
(*Indeterminate*)
```

The left question is:

- Is there a method of preventing the pattern matcher from matching `"a"->0` as `_Symbol[___]` without affecting the efficiency too much?

Comment: Related:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8619,
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/178285

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thx! I've made a mistake in the question and the result is that the second definition is always shadowed by the first.

Comment: I've decided to close this question since: 1) the first question has been explored in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8619 2) the second question seems valueless and I'll implement the related functions in another way.