# Error Message when nothing should be evaluated

Tags: series-expansion, assignment

When I try to define this simple function

```
getCoeff[SeriesData[_, _, coeff_, _, _, _]] := coeff[[2]]
```

I get an error:

```
SeriesData: Coefficient specification coeff_ in SeriesData[_,_,coeff_,_,_,_] is not a list.
```

Can someone explain what's wrong with this? My understanding was that `SetDelayed` shouldn't complain about such things because until I actually evaluate an expression containing `getCoeff` it shouldn't try to evaluate `Part[coeff,2]`.

There is no error thrown for the similar function

```
f[g[_, _, x_, _, _, _]] := x[[2]]
```

and furthermore `getCoeff` works as expected:

```
getCoeff@Series[E^(\[Pi] x), {x, 0, 3}]
```

outputs $\pi$.

I know the "right" way to manipulate `SeriesData`, I'd just like to understand this case for its own sake.

Comment: Use unevaluated: `getCoeff[Unevaluated[SeriesData[_, _, coeff_, _, _, _]]] := 
  coeff[[2]];` Then `getCoeff@Series[E^(\[Pi] x), {x, 0, 3}] = \[Pi]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to the special behavior of [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`) with regards to the first argument (see e.g. [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95557/why-is-the-first-argument-of-the-setdelayed-evaluated)): The arguments of the l.h.s. are evaluated by `SetDelayed`, which causes the error you are seeing - after all, `SeriesData[_, _, coeff_, _, _, _]` is not a valid `SeriesData` construct. This is what [`HoldPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html) is designed for: It prevents evaluation of its argument (like [`Hold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html)), but is invisible to the pattern matcher. The solution is therefore simply:

```
(* prevent the l.h.s. from being evaluated *)
HoldPattern@getCoeff[SeriesData[_, _, coeff_, _, _, _]] := coeff[[2]]

getCoeff@Series[E^(π x), {x, 0, 3}]
(* π *)

(* prevent only evaluation of the first argument (equivalent in this case) *)
getCoeff[HoldPattern@SeriesData[_, _, coeff_, _, _, _]] := coeff[[2]]

getCoeff@Series[E^(π x), {x, 0, 3}]
(* π *)
```

As noted in the comments, the original version works perfectly fine ignoring the error message: If you look at `?getCoeff`, you'll see that the definition that was actually made is the same with and without `HoldPattern`. If you evaluate `SeriesData[_, _, coeff_, _, _, _]` on its own, you will see that you get the error message, and then the input will be returned (which happens for many Mathematica functions) - if you would have gotten something else back, the definition would not work.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! However I still wonder: why does the code seem to work anyway? If I left it as it was, would there be any consequences other than the error message?

Comment: No, in this case there would be no consequence: If you look at `?getCoeff`, you'll see that the definition that was actually made is the same with and without `HoldPattern`. If you evaluate `SeriesData[_, _, coeff_, _, _, _]` on its own, you will see that you get the error message, and then the input will be returned (which happens for many Mathematica functions) - if you would have gotten something else back, the definition would not work