# Why Optional in Set is not held by the HoldFirst attribute?

Tags: evaluation, options, hold, assignment, optional-arguments

When evaluating`f[x_:x0] := x`, `x0` will be evaluated, regardless of the `HoldAll` attribute of `SetDelayed`.

Why the second argument of `Optional` is evaluated in a non-standard manner?

Comment: Can you show us how the evaluation is non-standard?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95583/1871

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the "Details" of the docs for [`HoldPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html)

> The left-hand sides of rules are usually evaluated, as are parts of the left-hand sides of assignments. You can use `HoldPattern` to stop any part from being evaluated.

Application:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[HoldPattern[x_: x0]] := x;

x0 = 7;

f[5]
f[]
(*
  5
  7
*)

Block[{x0 = 3},
 f[]
 ]
(*  3  *)
```