# Iteration of functions

Tags: functions

I'm trying to define a function f, such that

```
f[a_]:=a;

f[f[a__]]:=f[a];
```

Then, I tried to evaluate `f[x,y]`. Since `f[x,y]` satisfies none of these two patterns, it is expected that the result will be just `f[x,y]`. Nevertheless, in fact, the result is

```
Hold[f(a,b)]
```

and I get a error message:

> $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded. >>

It seems quite confusing. How could this happen?

Comment: Greetings! To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: You're looking for the [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat.html) attribute.

Comment: Also, take a look at `?f`. Another way to achieve the desired result would be `f[Hold@f[a__]]:=f[a];`.

Comment: @rcollyer,@Graumagier.Thanks for all of your help. I changed my code by replacing the second line by SetAttributes[f,Flat]. However, the problem remained.

Comment: I'm not really sure `Flat` does what you want to do. Did you try `f[Hold@f[a__]]:=f[a];`? Also take care to clear all definitions/restart the kernel.

Comment: @ Graumagier, I tried this method, the problem is solved. However, I couldn't get the desired result--Flatting the function.

Answer (score 6):

Note the following

```
a=3;
g[a]=2;
g//Definition
```

> g[3]=2

We see that the definition `g[3]=2` was stored, rather than `g[a]=2`. The argument of `g`, which is `a`, is evaluated before the definition is made.

The same happens in your code. `f[a__]` evaluates to `a__` before the definition is made.

```
f//Definition
```

> ```
> f[a_]:=a
> f[a__]:=f[a]
> ```

I like the following solution

```
f4[a_] := a;
f4[HoldPattern@f4[a__]] := f4[a];
```

Another solution relies on using `Unevaluated` in a strange and AFAIK undocumented way, like this

```
f2[a_] := a;
f2[Unevaluated@f2[a__]] := f2[a];
f2 // Definition
```

> ```
> f2[f2[a__]]:=f2[a] 
> f2[a_]:=a
> ```

I kind of like this too, because it allows you to make the definition you want to make, without `HoldPattern`.

Comment: I have quited the kernel before runing these two lines of codes. How could the arguments be evaluated?

Comment: @WenChern it is just what _Mathematica_ does. I suppose the case of the example of `g` was the main case that was focused on in making this decision.

Comment: The problem arises if you evaluate `f[a_]=a` prior to `f[f[a__]]=f[a]`, because first `f[a_]` gets "replaced" with `a`, and then `f[f[a__]]=f[a]` evaluates to `f[a__]=f[a]`.

Comment: @Graumagier yes, this is essentially Chris Degnens solution. My own solution is something that may be nice to see for more experienced users. I suppose it also explicitly reminds you of the problem, which can be nice.

Comment: Sure, your solution is definitely more robust. I just tried to explain the problem to Wen Chern, but your comment was put up first ;)

Comment: @Graumagier,@Jacob Akkerboom. Thank for your help. The problem is well solved. I think I get your points now.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the expected output by defining the functions in reverse order.

```
f[f[a__]] := f[a]
f[a_] := a

f[x, y]
```

> f[x, y]

Comment: Thank you very much. Though I don't know how this method works, it does solve the problem.

Comment: @WenChern it changes the order in which the patterns are tested. Since `f[f[a]]` matches both `f[a_]` and `f[f[a__]]`, you need to change the order they're stored in (cf. [`DownValues`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/52), and the answers). This is most easily effected by changing the order they're declared in. Note, however, there is a notion of specificity, where more specific patterns are tested before more general ones. In this case, though, they're equally general.

Comment: @rcollyer unless I am mistaken, this is not what is going on. The pattern `f[f[a__]]` is more specific than `f[a_]`, so in this sense the order should not matter. In the example `f7[a_] := a;
f7[{a__}] := f7[a];` the `DownValues` are automatically sorted for this reason. The reason for the trouble is that in the other order of evaluation, there is an unexpected evaluation of a pattern. Please see my answer.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom you're correct. I misread `DownValues@f`, completely missing the transformation.

Comment: @rcollyer to be honest this is something I could easily have missed while writing code myself. It is nice to be reminded of this danger IMO.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom yes it does.

Answer (score 3):

[Jacob](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98471/52) gives a good exposition on different methods that work. But, to avoid any possibility of ambiguity, I would go with something very different

```
f[a_] := a
f[q_f] := q
```

which is correctly ordered

```
DownValues@f
(* {HoldPattern[f[q_f]] :> q, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> a} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your double uderscore (`BlankSequence`) in the second definition matches things like x,y.  For example:

```
f[a__] := 10*a;
f[3, 2, 4]
240
```

Comment: Sure it does, but by Wen Chern's intuition neither `f[f[a__]]` nor `f[a_]` should match `f[x,y]` (and they don't actually). Only in the above combination they do.

Comment: @Graumagier I guess I don't really understand what the desired result is.

Comment: As I understand it the expression `f[x,y]` should be returned unevaluated because it is not of the form `f[f[a__]]` (a function inside a function).