# Creating an indexed set of functions with the indices in the function names

Tags: functions, string-manipulation

As the titles describes, I want to create a list of functions like the following, where the indices are not in the argument slots:

```
f1[x_]=a1*x;
f2[x_]=a2*x;
f3[x_]=a3*x;
... 
fn[x_]=an*x;
```

This is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
ToExpression["f"<>ToString[k]][x_]=ToExpression["a"<>ToString[k]]*x
```

So how should the code be written?

Comment: But why do you want to do this? In my experience, it's *always* better to use either `SubValues` or just straight-up `Downvalues`. Anyway, something like `f[k][x_] = a[k]*x`. If you really feel the need, replace `ToExpression` with `Symbol`, but in general this type of thing is unnecessary and perhaps even detrimental. Just do my first suggestion.

Comment: As march says, this really isn't a good way to do things. Nevertheless: `With[{idx = IntegerString[1]}, Set @@ Hold[Symbol["f" <> idx][x_], Symbol["a" <> idx] x]]` (I'm not posting this as an answer since I don't want to.)

Comment: @march Thank you for the advice! Yes I think `f[k][x_] = a[k]*x` is better, at least far simpler. By the way, what are SubValues? I searched for the term in the Help documents but didn't find it.

Comment: @User18. See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues).

Comment: @J. M. Thanks for the comment. I tried the code, but when I entered `f6[x]`, for instance, the output is still `f6[x]`, instead of `a6*x`. What's wrong?

Comment: @march That's a good resource.

Comment: Maybe you have uncleared definitions. Run ``ClearAll["Global`*"]`` and try my snippet again.

Comment: @J. This I what I tried, still without the desired result: ClearAll["Global`*"];
With[{idx = IntegerString[1]}, 
  Set @@ Hold[Symbol["f" <> idx][x_], Symbol["a" <> idx] x]];
f6[x]

Comment: Sigh... replace `IntegerString[1]` with `IntegerString[6]`. I thought it was sufficiently apparent, but I guess not.

Comment: @J. M. OK, thanks. : )

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Thank you! That page has exactly the things I'd  like to know, including, in particular, the Notation Package.

Comment: That question linked to uses a title that contains too little information about  what it is really about, to be readily found by searching.

Comment: I agree, that's why the system of marking as duplicate exists, so someone will find your question and follow the link to the duplicate.

Comment: Marking a question as duplicate is not meant to patronize a user, but to link existing threads, precisely to mitigate bad titling, etc, so as to facilitate easier searching.

Comment: I agree. My question is much easier to find. : )