# How can PowerExpand be made to evaluate the ArcTan form that takes two arguments?

Tags: expression-manipulation, trigonometry

Consider

```
c = Cos[phi];
s = Sin[phi];
ArcTan[c, s] // PowerExpand
ArcTan[s/c] // PowerExpand
```

which yields

```
ArcTan[Cos[phi], Sin[phi]]
phi
```

Oddly, `PowerExpand` does not find its way with the *two argument* version of `ArcTan`. However, it does with the *single argument* `ArcTan`, as expected.

I like to use `ArcTan` with two arguments since it does not suffer from division by zero unless numerator and denominator are zero.

How can I tell `PowerExpand` to find its way into all inverse triginometric functions (assuming positive real variables, etc)?

What side effect would I suffer, if I attach a rule to `PowerExpand` or better yet to inverse trigonometric functions to deal with `ArcTan[c, s]` as `ArcTan[s/c]`? What other identities around trigonometric and inverse trigonometric functions and the exponential function that would also fit such considerations?

Comment: You might consider using the identity $$\arctan(x,y)=2\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$$ as a replacement rule...

Comment: I think the two argument form is intended to be used as computational convenience and not as a mathematical function.

Comment: @m_goldberg  the 2-argument form of `ArcTan` is the only way to recover the angle in the correct quadrant, so it is a distinct function from the 1-argument form.

Comment: @adalbert-hanßen, I don't foresee any negative consequences of doing `Unprotect[PowerExpand];
PowerExpand[ArcTan[a_, b_]] := PowerExpand[ArcTan[b/a]];
Protect[PowerExpand];`  It gives the return that you are looking for

Comment: @JasonB. I am well aware of that. But I don't see how your comment either illuminates or invalidates my comment. My point, to clarify it, is that I don't think the two argument form is meant for symbolic work where `PowerExpand` is relevant.

Comment: @m_goldberg Okay, I guess I still dont know what you mean by it being used not as a mathematical function.

Comment: @JasonB. I recommend using up-values. `Unprotect[ArcTan]; PowerExpand[ArcTan[a_, b_]] ^:= 
 PowerExpand[ArcTan[b/a]]; Protect[ArcTan];`

Comment: @m_goldberg - can you elaborate on why, in this particular case, it's better to apply the rule as an upvalue to ArcTan rather than as a downvalue to PowerExpand?  I get that upvalues are [more localized in general](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127/9490) than downvalues, but in this case I don't see what the difference would be.

Comment: For your consideration: `ArcTan[x, y] // TrigToExp` ;)

Comment: @J.M. - now try `ArcTan[c, s] // TrigToExp // FullSimplify` and then tell me why that doesn't simplify further... Scratch that, I see my mistake

Comment: @Jason, the fact that `Exp[]` is $2\pi i$-periodic has something to do with it. ;)

Comment: @JasonB. In your version, the new rule will be considered every time `PowerExpand` is called, even when the expression being evaluated has nothing to do with `ArcTan`. With `^:=` is will only considered when `Arctan` has been seen as an argument.