# How to use the symbols in System`Private`?

Tags: undocumented

Looking at Names["System`Private`*"] gives:

[image]

I'd really like to use and look at the code for some of these symbols, e.g.

```
System`Private`AlgebraicNumberQ
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There are numerous [undocumented functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805/52) in Mathematica, and a lot of them are useful for regular users. They're just regular functions, but figuring out the calling syntax can be tricky, especially if they don't have [`DownValues`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/52). But, with ``System`Private`AlgebraicNumberQ`` it's pretty clear: ``System`Private`AlgebraicNumberQ[number]``. When `number` is `Pi` or `E` it returns `False` (they're transcendental), but `Sqrt[2]` is `True`.

Comment: @J.M. I was looking for that question.

Comment: @rcollyer, it's sorta kinda hard to forget an answer like ilian's. ;)

Comment: @J.M. I remembered it; I just couldn't find it, nor did I recall who wrote it. At least I got the opportunity to upvote it, finally. :)