# Syntax f[x_][y_]

Tags: function-construction, syntax

Need to understand the principle of the distinction between f[x_,y_] and  f[x_][y_]

It seems also that

```
z[x_, y_][a_, b_, c_][α_, β_] :=  a (x + y)^b + c/(α-β)
```

is interpreted by *Mathematica* since

```
Plot3D[z[x, y][2, 5, 3][2, 4], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

gives a nice plot. It could be useful to distinguish between variables and two types of parameters. But, in that case, how to use association like

```
data1 = Association[Thread[{"a", "b", "c"} -> {.5, 1, 1}]]
data2 = Association[Thread[{"α", "β"} -> {.2, 3}]]
```

--- how to use Apply --- @@ ---

NB David Park shows to me that how to do in the simple following case

```
b[x_][y_] := x^y
da = Association[Thread[{"x"} -> {.5}]]
(b @@ Values[da])[y]
```

If the association is on the first bracket-couple I can reproduce the example, but I do not know how to do it for a second bracket association.

Comment: Look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(z[x, y]@@(Values[data1]))@@(Values[data2])
(* or  z[x, y][##&@@(Values[data1])][##&@@(Values[data2])] *)
```

> -0.357143+0.5 (x+y)

```
Plot3D[(z[x, y]@@(Values[data1]))@@(Values[data2]), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
(* or Plot3D[z[x, y][##&@@(Values[data1])][##&@@(Values[data2])], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]