# Can I add options for my function?

Tags: options

```
Options[f]={"a"->Red}
(* {a -> Red} *)

f[Name][x_,options:OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Block[{},
    Plot[x, {x,0,10}, PlotStyle -> OptionValue[f,"a"]];
    OptionValue[f, "a"]
  ]

f[Name][x,"a"->Black]
```

The OptionValue of is always `Red`

### Sols：

```
Options[f]={"a"->Red}; 
f[Name][x_,opts:OptionsPattern[f]]:=Plot[x,{x,0,10},PlotStyl‌​e->OptionValue[f,{op‌​ts},"a"]] 
f[Name][x,"a"->Black]
```

Comment: The issue is that you attach your option to `f` but use a `SubValue` of `f`.

Comment: See also [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues)

Comment: @Sascha thanks, solved  `Options[f]={"a"->Red};
f[Name][x_,opts:OptionsPattern[f]]:=Plot[x,{x,0,10},PlotStyle->OptionValue[f,{opts},"a"]]
f[Name][x,"a"->Black]`