# Difference between variables and functions

Tags: functions, variable-definitions

Forgive me if this question is very basic; I've learned Mathematica mostly by example.

In most programming languages, there is a clear distinction between variables and functions: variables hold values, and functions take some values and return some others. But in Mathematica this becomes fuzzy. For example, I could this:

```
f = x^2
f /. x->2
Plot[f, {x,1,2}]
```

or this:

```
f[x_] := x^2
f[2]
Plot[f[x], {x,1,2}]
```

and in both cases I get the same result, namely 4 and a plot. I understand the difference between `=` and `:=` as having to do with delayed vs. immediate evaluation, but the overall difference between the two ways of defining "functions" is not so clear. Where would these produce different results? Why would you choose one over the other?

Comment: This feels like a really big question. The reason there's not quite a clear distinction between these two is that everything in *Mathematica* is an expression, and *Mathematica* applies replacement rules to the expressions; these rules are attached to the symbols, and depending on the pattern in the replacement rule, the replacement works in slightly different ways...

Comment: A big question, but for everyday life, not a big problem : try not to use the first block of code, because if you do `x=1` before your code, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: If you're looking for a deeper understanding, [Leonid's book/tutorial](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/) is a great place to start.

Comment: It is somewhat a terminology issue, but very roughly, I would call a function any construct that has a clear and explicit way to pass its arguments into its body, while a variable is simply  a reference to an expression it stores.

Comment: Your feeling is anticipated in the docs: [Everything Is an Expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html). The distinction between "variable" and "functions" begins with understanding the [different kinds of values](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues) symbols can have and how they are applied in the evaluation sequence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Advice**

The definition of what we think of as a "function", i.e.

```
f[x_] := x^2
```

is *safer* than

```
g = x^2
```

because in the first case, `x` isn't a global variable but rather the name of a `Pattern` to be matched, whereas in the second case, `x` refers to some (possible undefined but maybe not!) global symbol, and so you can run into issues. For instance, you might have set `x` to a number previously and forgotten about it, which then leads to problems in later code. Maybe 1% of the questions we get here arise from this very issue.

**Disambiguation/Explanation**

The reason there's not quite a clear distinction between these two is that in *Mathematica*, [Everything is an Expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html), and Mathematica applies replacement rules to the expressions; these rules are attached to the symbols, and depending on the pattern in the replacement rule, the replacement works in slightly different ways.

To illustrate with your examples:

```
Clear@g
g = x^2;
OwnValues@g
(* {HoldPattern[g] :> x^2} *)
```

Associated with `g` is a replacement rule that replaces every instance of `g` with the expression `x^2` automatically.

```
Clear@f
f[x_] = x^2;
DownValues@f 
(* {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x^2} *)
```

`x_` is a `Pattern` that matches any expression (it is a wild-card), and names the expression `x` so that it can be used on the right-hand side of a rule. Associated with `f` is a replacement rule that replaces every instance of `f[x_]`---that is "f-of-something"--- with the expression `x^2` automatically. Note that when this matches, the `x` isn't the symbol `x` but rather whatever was put in the `x_` spot.

```
f[2]
(* 4 *)
f[a + Sin[b]]
(* (a + Sin[b])^2 *)
```

This becomes important when you have to worry about scoping. In your plot examples, both

```
Plot[g, {x, 1, 2}]
Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 2}]
```

work, but this because `Plot` effectively uses the `Block` scoping construct, which blocks off any definitions of the symbol `x` but still uses that symbol. Another scoping construct is `Module`, which actually creates a new symbol.

For instance, note the following behavior. Using again

```
Clear@f
f[x_] = x^2;
```

Then `Block` does this:

```
Block[{x}, Print[x]; x = 2; Print[f[x]]]
(* x *)
(* 4 *)
```

Contrast this with `Module`, which does this:

```
Module[{x}, Print[x]; x = 2; Print[f[x]]]
(* x$3780 *)
(* 4 *)
```

Within `Module`, we declare `x` as a variable local to the construct, but behind the scenes *Mathematica* re-names the variable. `Block` doesn't do that. However, since we use `f[x]` in `Module`, `x` in `f[x]` is interpreted as the *local* `x`, and so it evaluates to 4.

Now, for the other version:

```
Clear@g
g = x^2;
```

Then,

```
Block[{x}, Print[x]; x = 2; Print[g]]
(* x *)
(* 4 *)
```

and

```
Module[{x}, Print[x]; x = 2; Print[g]]
(* x$3776 *)
(* x^2 *)
```

Because `g` is directly replaced with `x^2`, rather than the `Pattern` `f[pat_]` getting replaced by `pat^2`, `Module` treats the two `x`'s as different objects, and so `g` evaluates to `x^2` in `Module. In`Block`, the symbols are interpreted as the same, so`g` evaluates to 4.

For more information about scoping, see [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs)