# Why doesn't CloudDeploy work in my desktop

Tags: deployment, cloud-deploy

I have difficulty in making CloudDeploy in my desktop. Does anyone know why ? Thanks

Here is what I see:

[image]

---

Here is the code if someone would like to test

```
CloudDeploy[
 Manipulate[
  f[x] = Sin[x];
  Plot[f[k x], {x, 0, 10}], {k, 1, 10}]

 ]
```

Mathematica 11.0

Comment: Here its considered helpful to show your own efforts and share your code in a **[well formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) instead of images** or links to external files, so we can quickly **Copy&Paste** your code, test it, and  see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly. This [question in Meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-should-i-include-code-samples-in-posts) could be useful.

Comment: Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context,  **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using? The same code works for me without issues. What happens if you evaluate `$CloudConnected`?

Comment: When I evaluate $CloudConnected, it just returns the same thing to me.

Comment: `$CloudConnected` should return `True`. Read the documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$CloudConnected.html).

Comment: It appears to me that the problem lies in the [function definition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html). The form used in the question is something I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: @AiltonAndradedeOliveira why, can you reproduce the problem and is it fixed when you change definition?

Comment: @Joey try a fresh start: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464 and if this does not help try contacting WRI Support. Your code should work but noone else can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the function definition.

```
CloudDeploy[
 Manipulate[
  f[x_] := Sin[x];
  Plot[f[k x], {x, 0, 10}], {k, 1, 10}]
 ]
```

Note that I am changing **`f[x]=Sin[x]`** to **`f[x_]:=Sin[x]`**. The key points here are:

- **`x`** to **`x_`** (the use of a [Pattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html), the main change here)
- **`=`** to **`:=`** (the use of [SetDelayed](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html), optional but I would suggest as a good habit for *Mathematica* newcomers).

I welcome more experienced users to clarify here, but I like to think *Mathematica* as a kind of term rewriting system. When I say `f[x]=Sin[x]` all that is said to *Mathematica* is "if you find *literally* `f[x]` change it to `Sin[x]` (it is creating a kind of **DownValues** - a good question regarding related concepts is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/98)). Normally, a newcomer **do not** want this. You would expect to create something that would allow `f[3]` to be understood as `Sin[3]`. This is where **Patterns** come to rescue."

Comment: That's all true but how does this answer the problem about `CloudDeploy`? I can use OP's code and deploy it, sure it won't work correctly but that is not the point here.

Comment: @Kuba, I think the main problem is a corrupted session (I +1'ed your comment suggesting a fresh start). I was only able to reproduce the problem by **clearing** `CloudDeploy`. However, the syntax used could fail if a Symbol x was already present in the session. Because of this I decided to point to more robust ways of defining functions and related concepts.