# Define scalar quantity that squares to 1?

Tags: replacement, variable-definitions, rule

My equations contain different cases which differ only by some signs. So in order to work with all cases simultaneously, I introduce a placeholder for a sign:

```
s[x]
```

where `x` labels which sign that is. Now when I perform manipulations of my terms, I encounter higher powers of the same sign, like `s[1]^2`. Of course the square of a sign should be just `s[1]^2=1`, so I try to define a rule:

```
s[x_]^2:=1
```

> SetDelayed::write: Tag Power in s[x_]^2 is Protected.

As you can see, there is an error message and the rule does not get set. How should I be going about defining a rule that sets the square of any `s[x]` to `1`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) i.e.:

```
s /: s[x_]^2 := 1
```

This will create a substitution rule ([UpValue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96)) for symbol `s`,
which is only applied, when `s` is inside `Power[s[_], 2]`.

Comment: Thank you! I went with `s /: s[x_]^n_Integer /; n > 1 := s[x]^Mod[n, 2]`.