# Multiple Square Bracketed Function definition

Tags: functions, function-construction, functional-style

I am familiar with the typical way of defining a function--such as

```
f[x_,y_]:=x+y
```

but I have not found a discussion of definitions such as

```
torus[a_,b_,c_][p_,q_][u_,v_]:= {(a+b Cos[u])Cos[v],(a+b Cos[u])Sin[v},c Sin[u]}
```

I am not asking about this specific example but the `f[][][]:=` structure as opposed to the usual  `f[]:=` simpler one.  Can someone point me to a discussion?

Comment: perhaps you'll find [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues) useful; (look for `SubValues`)

Comment: See also [`Expressions with Heads That Are Not Symbols`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExpressionsWithHeadsThatAreNotSymbols.html) and [`Making Definitions for Indexed Objects`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html)

Comment: [search results on this site for "currying"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=currying)?