# Get imaginary part of symbolic expression

Tags: symbolic, complex

I define

```
ψ1 = Sqrt[Subscript[ρ, 1][t]] E^(I Subscript[θ, 1][t]);
ψ2 = Sqrt[Subscript[ρ, 2][t]] E^(I Subscript[θ, 2][t]);
```

and

```
eq1 = (I ℏ D[ψ1, t] - U ψ1 - K ψ2)/E^(I Subscript[θ, 1][t]) // FullSimplify
```

gives

[image]

I want to get the imaginary part of the above expression where $\rho$ is positive, and $\theta$ is real.

The result should be

[image]

while `ComplexExpand` gives

[image]

How do I do it correctly?

Comment: If you simplify assuming `Subscript[ρ, 1][t] > 0` and `Subscript[ρ, 2][t] > 0`, it works as expected

Comment: FYI, You should avoid using [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a composite expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [Downvalue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102/10397) to the operator `Subscript` and not an Ownvalue to an indexed `x` as you may intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

Here are your expressions:

```
ψ1 = 
  Sqrt[Subscript[ρ, 1][t]] E^(I Subscript[θ, 1][t]);
ψ2 = 
  Sqrt[Subscript[ρ, 2][t]] E^(I Subscript[θ, 2][t]);
eq1 = 
  (I*ℏ D[ψ1, t] - U ψ1 - k ψ2)/E^(I Subscript[θ, 1][t]) // FullSimplify
```

[image]

I assume, your K is not the reserved Mma constant and replaced it, therefore, by the small k above.

Let us now represent the exponent in the trigonometric form and replace the imaginary unit by any letter, say, by X for further use:

```
eq2 = ExpToTrig[eq1];
eq3=eq2 /. Complex[0, a_] -> X*a
```

[image]

Now this:

```
Coefficient[eq3, X]
```

makes the job:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Great, I actually tried i->x before, however, it can not replace the i/2. Clever trick for Complex[0, a_] -> X*a